# UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode - character maps to <undefined>, print function

Tags: python, encoding, decode, encode

I am writing a Python (Python 3.3) program to send some data to a webpage using POST method.  Mostly for debugging process I am getting the page result and displaying it on the screen using `print()` function.

The code is like this:

```
conn.request("POST", resource, params, headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
print(response.status, response.reason)
data = response.read()
print(data.decode('utf-8'));
```

the `HTTPResponse` `.read()` method returns a `bytes` element encoding the page (which is a well formated UTF-8 document)  It seemed okay until I stopped using IDLE GUI for Windows and used the Windows console instead.  The returned page has a U+2014 character (em-dash) which the print function translates well in the Windows GUI (I presume Code Page 1252) but does not in the Windows Console (Code Page 850).  Given the `strict` default behavior I get the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2014' in position 10248: character maps to <undefined>
```

I could fix it using this quite ugly code:

```
print(data.decode('utf-8').encode('cp850','replace').decode('cp850'))
```

Now it replace the offending character "—" with a `?`.  Not the ideal case (a hyphen should be a better replacement) but good enough for my purpose.

There are several things I do not like from my solution.

1. The code is ugly with all that decoding, encoding, and decoding.
2. It solves the problem for just this case.  If I port the program for a system using some other encoding (latin-1, cp437, back to cp1252, etc.) it should recognize the target encoding.  It does not.  (for instance, when using again the IDLE GUI, the emdash is also lost, which didn't happen before)
3. It would be nicer if the emdash translated to a hyphen instead of a interrogation bang.

The problem is not the emdash (I can think of several ways to solve that particularly problem) but I need to write robust code.  I am feeding the page with data from a database and that data can come back.  I can anticipate many other conflicting cases: an 'Á' U+00c1 (which is possible in my database) could translate into CP-850 (DOS/Windows Console encodign for Western European Languages) but not into CP-437 (encoding for US English, which is default in many Windows instalations).

So, the question:

Is there a nicer solution that makes my code agnostic from the output interface encoding?

Comment: Related: [Python, Unicode, and the Windows console](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5419/4279)

Comment: Check this answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49004993/5774004

Comment: you are totally right, this is ugly but works like a charm, in my case using latin-1   print(data.decode('cp850').encode('latin-1','replace').decode('latin-1'))

Answer (score 117):

I see three solutions to this:

1. Change the output encoding, so it will always output UTF-8. See e.g. [Setting the correct encoding when piping stdout in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492483/setting-the-correct-encoding-when-piping-stdout-in-python), but I could not get these example to work.
2. Following example code makes the output aware of your target charset.

   ```
   # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
   import sys

   print sys.stdout.encoding
   print u"Stöcker".encode(sys.stdout.encoding, errors='replace')
   print u"Стоескер".encode(sys.stdout.encoding, errors='replace')
   ```

   This example properly replaces any non-printable character in my name with a question mark.

   If you create a custom print function, e.g. called `myprint`, using that mechanisms to encode output properly you can simply replace print with `myprint` whereever necessary without making the whole code look ugly.
3. Reset the output encoding globally at the begin of the software:

   The page http://www.macfreek.nl/memory/Encoding_of_Python_stdout has a good summary what to do to change output encoding. Especially the section "StreamWriter Wrapper around Stdout" is interesting. Essentially it says to change the I/O encoding function like this:

   In Python 2:

   ```
   if sys.stdout.encoding != 'cp850':
     sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('cp850')(sys.stdout, 'strict')
   if sys.stderr.encoding != 'cp850':
     sys.stderr = codecs.getwriter('cp850')(sys.stderr, 'strict')
   ```

   In Python 3:

   ```
   if sys.stdout.encoding != 'cp850':
     sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('cp850')(sys.stdout.buffer, 'strict')
   if sys.stderr.encoding != 'cp850':
     sys.stderr = codecs.getwriter('cp850')(sys.stderr.buffer, 'strict')
   ```

   If used in CGI outputting HTML you can replace 'strict' by 'xmlcharrefreplace' to get HTML encoded tags for non-printable characters.

   Feel free to modify the approaches, setting different encodings, .... Note that it still wont work to output non-specified data. So any data, input, texts must be correctly convertable into unicode:

   ```
   # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
   import sys
   import codecs
   sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter("iso-8859-1")(sys.stdout, 'xmlcharrefreplace')
   print u"Stöcker"                # works
   print "Stöcker".decode("utf-8") # works
   print "Stöcker"                 # fails
   ```

Comment: I currently not have my Windows test platform, but I tested in Linux (Ubuntu), with my terminal set to UTF-8 and it worked okay.  However I changed my terminal to ISO-8859-15 and it doesn't print right.  The output went as:
UTF-8
StÃ¶cker
Ð¡ÑÐŸÐµÑÐºÐµÑ

Comment: Hi, I added a third point, which solves that issue for me. Regarding the above: "sys.stdout.encoding" probably does not know your terminal encoding, but only the system-wide encoding. If this is not equal to the terminal, then only parsing some environment variables may help. But that wont work always, as a terminal must not tell the other side its encoding. So the sending side can't ALWAYS know the encoding when it differs from the system.

Comment: Python 3: `sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.detach(), sys.stdout.encoding, 'replace')`. Or use `'backslashreplace'` to preserve the ordinal value (but possibly misalign output formatting).

Comment: @eryksun: or use `win-unicode-console` package to print Unicode directly whatever `chcp` is. Or set `PYTHONIOENCODING=:replace` envvar (outside your script). No need to change your script if it prints Unicode already, configure your environment instead.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, I prefer the `win_unicode_console` approach over setting environment variables. It "just works".

Comment: @eryksun: yes, but the envvar is useful if the output is redirected to a file/pipe.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, it was short-sighted for Python 3 to use the legacy ANSI codepage for a non-interactive standard stream. It's based on `locale.getpreferredencoding`. Even in the latest VC 14 the locale implementation doesn't allow UTF-8 (e.g. for `wcstombs`); it's all legacy codepage based and should be avoided (IMO). Now it's too late to change the default encoding to UTF-8. This affects the subprocess module as well, since it's the default for `universal_newlines=True`. Hopefully Python 4 gets this right.

Comment: @eryksun: and Python 3.6 corrects that now.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, 3.6 uses UTF-8 for bytes with os functions. I have a pending patch to extend this to `os.environb`. UTF-8 is also used for the `buffer` and `raw` interfaces for the `sys.std*` files, but only for the Windows console, i.e. when using `io.WindowsConsoleIO`. If it's a file or pipe it still defaults to the legacy ANSI encoding. The same applies to `subprocess.Popen`, but at least we now have `encoding` and `errors` parameters. Steve Dower proposed to make UTF-8 the preferred encoding on Windows, but that wasn't implemented. Maybe in 3.8.

Comment: @eryksun: you should never rely on `locale.getpreferredencoding()` for file I/O on any platform, that's not unique to Windows, and you can trivially set that to a proper codec explicitly.

Comment: @eryksun: I can *sort of* see the point of `encoding` still defaulting to `locale.getpreferredencoding()` on Windows (like it does on any platform), because *other tools* still use that same setting when they are doing I/O. You'd need to fix the whole ecosystem; is Python in a position to dictate that direction on Windows?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, for standard I/O you have to either set the `PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable or rebind `sys.std*`. There's an open issue to allow changing the encoding of a `TextIOWrapper`, which will make this simpler. `Popen` should continue to default to ANSI, and we also have the option to use OEM now. As to the preferred encoding, yes the issue with general ecosystem on Windows was what held up making that change. One idea that was proposed is a hybrid system that uses 'utf-8-sig' for new files and detects the BOM for existing files and otherwise uses ANSI.

Answer (score 38):

Based on Dirk Stöcker's answer, here's a neat wrapper function for Python 3's print function. Use it just like you would use print.

As an added bonus, compared to the other answers, this won't print your text as a bytearray ('b"content"'), but as normal strings ('content'), because of the last decode step.

```
def uprint(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout):
    enc = file.encoding
    if enc == 'UTF-8':
        print(*objects, sep=sep, end=end, file=file)
    else:
        f = lambda obj: str(obj).encode(enc, errors='backslashreplace').decode(enc)
        print(*map(f, objects), sep=sep, end=end, file=file)

uprint('foo')
uprint(u'Antonín Dvořák')
uprint('foo', 'bar', u'Antonín Dvořák')
```

Comment: outputs: Antonín Dvo\u0159ák

Comment: Yes, that is the fallback if the output stream (e.g., your console) does not support the ř character: it will output the unicode code point in backslash notation: \uXXXX. You can substitute `'backslashreplace'` with another preference if that suits your case better: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode

Comment: The very nice code snippet, sufficient for my needs. Let me add that I used `uprint(f"Description: {repo_dict['description']}")` instead of `print(f"Description: {repo_dict['description']}")`. In practice, just add u before print.

Answer (score 25):

For debugging purposes, you could use `print(repr(data))`.

To display text, always print Unicode. Don't hardcode the character encoding of your environment such as *Cp850* inside your script. To decode the HTTP response, see [A good way to get the charset/encoding of an HTTP response in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14592762/4279).

To print Unicode to Windows console, you could [use `win-unicode-console` package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30551552/4279).

Comment: Now that Python 3.6 is out, perhaps include that as a recommendation too (as that version basically switched to the same solution as the `win-unicode-console` package).

Comment: @MartijnPieters if you click the link then you see Python3.6 recommendation.

Comment: Ah, that makes a better dupe target then for the most recent post asking about Windows console printing behaviour.

Comment: Pity that that question uses screenshots for the output, however. That's next to useless for searching.

Comment: @MartijnPieters [the canonical dupe target for "Windows console printing behavior"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5419/4279) is in turn [linked](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32176732/4279) in the linked answer at the very top.

Comment: I always search for a Python 3 specific one. I should drop `3` and just search for the error message plus print, obviously.

Comment: And one of these days I'll find the energy to dupe close all the rest. Today is not that day.

Answer (score 25):

I dug deeper into this and found the best solutions are here.

http://blog.notdot.net/2010/07/Getting-unicode-right-in-Python

In my case I solved "UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character "

original code:

```
print("Process lines, file_name command_line %s\n"% command_line))
```

New code:

```
print("Process lines, file_name command_line %s\n"% command_line.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: encode('utf-8') was the good thing to do in my case. Thanks

Answer (score 14):

If you are using Windows command line to print the data, you should use

```
chcp 65001
```

This worked for me!

Comment: This is no good. The output is extremely buggy prior to Windows 8, and non-ASCII input fails up through Windows 10. Upgrading to Python 3.6 or installing `win_unicode_console` is the way to get correct Unicode support in the Windows console.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Python 3.6 (possibly 3.5 or later), it doesn't give that error to me anymore.  I had a similar issue, because I was using v3.4, but it went away after I uninstalled and reinstalled.

Comment: This is not the issue here I think. I use 3.5.2 but getting the error.

Comment: @khaled4vokalz, no, upgrading to Python 3.6 does solve this issue. We switched to using the Windows console's Unicode API in 3.6. There's no more legacy codepage headaches.

Comment: This information is not correct. I am using python 3.8 and still getting the error.

Comment: I'm using python 3.10.4 and still getting the issue (use AWS CLI to get some international email templates)... I tried to export/set PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8 as some peeps rec but didn't work initially. However after a windows restart, That setting or this Beta Windows-10 UTF-8 setting seemed to work.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/201156

Comment: I'm using Python 3.9.16. And Python uses UTF-8 as a default encoding `$ python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.getdefaultencoding())'
utf-8`
and still does not work.