# Python except for UnicodeError?

Tags: python, python-3.3

In my code I keep getting this error...

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2013' in position 390: character maps to <undefined>
```

I tried to put an except for UnicodeError and UnicodeEncodeError but nothing works, the problem is it's the users input so I can't control what they put so I need all encode errors to display a print that says error instead of crashing the program...

```
try:
    argslistcheck = argslist[0]
    if argslistcheck[0:7] != "http://":
        argslist[0] = "http://" + argslist[0]
    with urllib.request.urlopen(argslist[0]) as url:
        source = url.read()
        source = str(source, "utf8")
    except urllib.error.URLError:
        print("Couln't connect")
        source = ""
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        print("There was an error encrypting...")
        source = ""
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ..... things leading up to error
  File "C:\path", line 99, in grab print(source)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2013' in position 390: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: It is more likely that it is the *output* of your program that is causing the error; Unicode data is automatically encoded to match your terminal output encoding. Are you printing anything or writing to a file? Please include that code and the full traceback.

Comment: Yes, it either prints the source or saves it to a txt file... It only does it on certain sites, like if I do it on my website then it wont, but if I do it with http://test.com/ then it would. I just don't want the program crashing.

Comment: Look closely at the traceback (preferably share it with us). It tells you *what operation* is failing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give this  a try:

`source = str(source, encoding='utf-8', errors = 'ignore')`

or take a look at [this post's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630288/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-character-maps-to-undefined).

Answer (score 5):

Your *print* is failing. Your Windows console doesn't support printing UTF-8, you need to change the codepage:

```
chcp 65001
```

This is a *Windows command*, not a python command. You may need to switch fonts too, Lucida Sans Console is a Unicode font that can handle a lot more glyphs.

Comment: Is there any encoding that would work yet not give me errors with bytes?

Comment: @TrevorPeyton: The problem is your input containing codepoints for which your default codepage (437) doesn't *have* any encoding. 65001 is the MS codepage for UTF-8, which *can* encode all of Unicode.

Comment: Thank you I got it from Ramces link he gave me.

Answer (score 3):

try this one to replace str():
`source = source.encode('UTF-8')`

Comment: That didn't work, the reason I encode it like that is because I'm changing it from byte to string. If I do that it gives me a different error about being a byte.

Answer (score 1):

```
start_url="https://www.indeed.co.in/jobs?q=teacher&l=India"
page_data=requests.get(start_url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(page_data.text,"lxml")
fname='1download'
with open(fname,'w')as f:
    f.write(soup.prettify())
f.close()

return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u20b9' in position 
235677: character maps to <undefined>
```

Both errors can be solved with adding utf-8 as encoding to file.also please note you have to use with open( ) method to open files

f=open() will also give you error

Here is the correct code:

```
 start_url="https://www.indeed.co.in/jobs?q=teacher&l=India"
 page_data=requests.get(start_url)
 soup=BeautifulSoup(page_data.text,"lxml")
 fname='1download'
 with open(fname,'w',encoding="utf-8")as f:
     f.write(soup.prettify())
 f.close()
```

Comment: I was missing ' encoding="utf-8" ' in the 'open' function which caused UnicodeEncodeError. After I added it, the error has gone.