# Python: error while trying to scrape youtube

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

while trying to scrape the homepage of youtube for the titles of each video im running this code

```
import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.youtube.com'
html = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, "html.parser")
print(soup('a'))
```

and its returning this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\kenda\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\youtube.py", line 7, in < 
<module>
print(soup('a'))
File "C:\Users\kenda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f384' in 
position 45442: character maps to <undefined>
[Finished in 4.83s]
```

how do i fix this? and why is it doing this specifically when im scraping youtube

Comment: Looks like you are trying to print a Christmas Tree (Emoji or something similar, I guess...) with bad encoding settings. Have you already had a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15056850/python-except-for-unicodeerror ?

Answer (score 1):

Urllib is much better and it's comfortable for use.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

The urlopen function will transform the url into html

```
url = 'https://www.youtube.com'
html = urlopen(url)
```

beautifulsoup will perse the html

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find_all('a'))
```

if you absolutely want to do it with requests, the solution is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.youtube.com'
resp = requests.get(url)
html = resp.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find_all('a'))
```

Comment: the requests module is much easier, i'd rather just figure out how to do this