# How to split a Python string on new line characters

Tags: python, string, split

In Python 3 in Windows 7 I read a web page into a string.

I then want to split the string into a list at newline characters.

I can't enter the newline into my code as the argument in `split()`, because I get a syntax error

> 'EOL while scanning string literal'

If I type in the characters `\` and `n`, I get a Unicode error.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: can u show some of ur text. and expected result

Comment: Could you copy and paste your *exact* code that gives a `UnicodeError`?

Comment: Here's the code: lines = page.split('\n'); 
 print (lines)

Comment: The error is not from the split, the error is from `print(lines)`.

Comment: To make this question better, can you **please provide an example input and expected results**. For example, the string `"Hello\nWorld"` becomes `["Hello", "World"]`. It is not clear how you read a web page to a string, and what you are expecting exactly. Also can you **please** show your code of how you read a web page into a string, how the string is composed (give a sample), and how you managed to get the EOL or Unicode error?

Answer (score 200):

#### ✨ Splitting line in Python:

Have you tried using `str.splitlines()` method?:

- [Python `2.X` documentation here.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines)
- [Python `3.X` documentation here.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines)

From the docs:

> [`str.splitlines([keepends])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines)
>
> Return a list of the lines in the string, breaking at line boundaries.
>   Line breaks are not included in the resulting list unless `keepends` is
>   given and true.

For example:

```
>>> 'Line 1\n\nLine 3\rLine 4\r\n'.splitlines()
['Line 1', '', 'Line 3', 'Line 4']

>>> 'Line 1\n\nLine 3\rLine 4\r\n'.splitlines(True)
['Line 1\n', '\n', 'Line 3\r', 'Line 4\r\n']
```

#### Which delimiters are considered?

> This method uses the universal newlines approach to splitting lines.

The main difference between Python `2.X` and Python `3.X` is that the former uses the universal newlines approach to splitting lines, so `"\r"`, `"\n"`, and `"\r\n"` are considered line boundaries for 8-bit strings, while the latter uses a superset of it that also includes:

- `\v` or `\x0b`: Line Tabulation (added in Python `3.2`).
- `\f` or `\x0c`: Form Feed (added in Python `3.2`).
- `\x1c`: File Separator.
- `\x1d`: Group Separator.
- `\x1e`: Record Separator.
- `\x85`: Next Line (C1 Control Code).
- `\u2028`: Line Separator.
- `\u2029`: Paragraph Separator.

#### splitlines VS split:

> Unlike [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) when a delimiter string *sep* is given, this method
>   returns an empty list for the empty string, and a terminal line break
>   does not result in an extra line:

```
>>> ''.splitlines()
[]

>>> 'Line 1\n'.splitlines()
['Line 1']
```

While `str.split('\n')` returns:

```
>>> ''.split('\n')
['']

>>> 'Line 1\n'.split('\n')
['Line 1', '']
```

#### ✂️ Removing additional whitespace:

If you also need to remove additional leading or trailing whitespace, like spaces, that are ignored by `str.splitlines()`, you could use `str.splitlines()` together with [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip):

```
>>> [str.strip() for str in 'Line 1  \n  \nLine 3 \rLine 4 \r\n'.splitlines()]
['Line 1', '', 'Line 3', 'Line 4']
```

#### ️ Removing empty strings (''):

Lastly, if you want to filter out the empty strings from the resulting list, you could use [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

```
>>> # Python 2.X:
>>> filter(bool, 'Line 1\n\nLine 3\rLine 4\r\n'.splitlines())
['Line 1', 'Line 3', 'Line 4']

>>> # Python 3.X:
>>> list(filter(bool, 'Line 1\n\nLine 3\rLine 4\r\n'.splitlines()))
['Line 1', 'Line 3', 'Line 4']
```

#### Additional comment regarding the original question:

As the error you posted indicates and Burhan suggested, the problem is from the print. There's a related question about that could be useful to you: [UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode - character maps to <undefined>, print function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630288/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-character-maps-to-undefined)

Comment: When I use lines = page.splitlines(), I get the error message that an integer is required. When I give it an integer, I get the Unicode error at the print.

Comment: Check the link I added, maybe you find a solution to your problem there.

Comment: For a portable function that provides ASCII splitting on byte and Unicode strings for both Python2 and Python3 see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72065730/2127439).

Comment: This is somewhat factually incorrect. Both splitlines versions are available in Python2 and Python 3, Only the names and the default have changed! Py2: str.splitlines() == Py3 bytes.splitlines(), Py2 unicode.splitlines == Py3 str.splitlines(). This causes much confusion. There is an issue on cpython, open since 2014: [str.splitlines splitting on non-\r\n characters - Issue \#66428 - python/cpython](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/66428).

Answer (score 3):

a.txt

```
this is line 1
this is line 2
```

code:

```
Python 3.4.0 (default, Mar 20 2014, 22:43:40) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> file = open('a.txt').read()
>>> file
>>> file.split('\n')
['this is line 1', 'this is line 2', '']
```

I'm on Linux, but I guess you just use `\r\n` on Windows and it would also work

Comment: And yes, you should show us your code that caused the error.

Comment: Here's the error message I get when I use '\n':Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SWO.py", line 108, in <module>
    print (lines)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xae' in position 45
204: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: @user1067305 You'd better add both the err msg and **code** to your question.

Comment: That message indicates that the contents of one or more of the split-up lines cannot be printed properly; it has nothing to do with the actual splitting process. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[python]+print+character+maps+to+undefined