# Datetime conversion errors due to multiple strings in a single cell in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` as follows where a `Date` field is present. I am reading this from excel using `pd.read_excel()` method.

```
    Company Code    Trxn_date                Company Name     Type
      20040       2019-05-11 00:00:00             ABC        Series A #<--the date is in `datetime` object only.
      20034       2019-04-26 00:00:00             XYZ        Series A
      20033       "5/15/2018\n23/4/2019"          PQR       "Series A  
                                                             Series B" # <-- In same row. 
      20040       2019-06-05 00:00:00             ABC        Series B
      20056        8/16/2019                      MNO        Series B
```

As you can see that for `20033` there are two entries in `Trxn_date` apart by `\n`. Same is true for `Type` field. Because of this, if I apply `pd.to_datetime(df['Trxn_date'])` I get an obvious error `TypeError: invalid string coercion to datetime`. I do not want to `coerce` option.

Please note that except `20033` and `20056` all dates are automatically converted to `datetime` object by pandas.

I would like to get the `df` as follows.

```
    Company Code    Trxn_date         Company Name    Type
      20040       2019-05-11            ABC         Series A   
      20034       2019-04-26            XYZ         Series A
      20033       2019-04-23            PQR         Series B  #<--Only the last date string is picked up and converted to datetime. 
      20040       2019-06-05            ABC         Series B
      20056       2019-08-16            MNO         Series B #<--The date format is changed to `yyyy-mm-dd`.
```

I am not able to get any clue to achieve the same above. For `20056` I can use `pd.to_datetime(df['Trxn_date'],errors='coerce').apply(lambda x  : x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') if pd.notnull(x) else ' ')`. This operation creates a blank in `Trxn_date` field for `20033`.

Can anybody give any insight on this?  May be I have to write a function and then use `lambda` for the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split by `\n` and get last lists by `str[-1]`, but [separator `\n` depends of real data, so should be different](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24237675/2901002):

```
df['Trxn_date'] = df['Trxn_date'].str.split('\n').str[-1]
df['Type'] = df['Type'].str.split('\n').str[-1]

df['Trxn_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Trxn_date'],errors='coerce').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: jezrael: I should have mentioned that except `20033` and `20056` all dates are automatically considered as `datetime` object. So when I apply your codes to mine, I get `NaT` for all the correct entries like `20040`, `20034` etc.

Comment: @pythondumb - So you need `df['Trxn_date'].astype(str).str.split('\n').str[-1]` ?

Comment: No this would pick up the `00:00:00` for all correct entries. Due to `str[-1]`.

Comment: @pythondumb -here is problem solution really depends of data in file, so is possible create excel file with your sample data and share it?

Comment: So you want me to share the excel file with the data as mentioned?

Comment: @pythondumb exactly.

Comment: sorry to ask, How to share an excel here? copy and paste the same?

Comment: @pythondumb you can send it to my email from my profile

Comment: I have taken care of the same, simply by declaring `converters={Trxn_date': str}`

Comment: @jezarel what if I want to get a latest date from the row `20033` i.e. between two dates, instead of `str[-1]` I should pick up the latest date.