# How to make str.splitlines method not to split line by hex characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I'm trying to parse output from GNU Strings utility with str.splitlines() 
Here is the raw output from GNU Strings:

```
279304 9k=pN\n 279340 9k=PN\n 279376 9k<LN\n 279412 9k=\x0cN\n 279448 9k<4N\n
```

When I parse the output with the following code:

```
process = subprocess.run(['strings', '-o', main_exe], check=True, \
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
output = process.stdout
print(output)
lines = output.splitlines()
for line in lines:
    print(line)
```

I get a result that I don't expect and it breaks my further parsing:

```
279304 9k=pN
279340 9k=PN
279376 9k<LN
279412 9k=
          N
279448 9k<4N
279592 9k<hN
279628 9k;TN
279664 9k<$N
```

Can I somehow tell the splitlines() method not trigger on `\x0` characters?

The desired result should have lines which starts with an offset (that 6 digits at the start of each line) :

```
279304 9k=pN
279340 9k=PN
279376 9k<LN
279412 9k=N
279448 9k<4N
279592 9k<hN
279628 9k;TN
279664 9k<$N
```

Comment: you could try not using splitlines but instead just use split and pass it only the new line char `lines = output.split('\n')`

Comment: Update your post with the desired result you woul like to get...

Comment: A good quick fix is `lines = [re.sub(r'(\r\n|\n)$', '', _l) for _l in StringIO(output)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you actually get the expected result. But assuming ASCII or any of its derevatives (Latin-x, UTF8, etc.) `'\x0c'` is the control character FormFeed which happens to be represented here as a vertical one line jump.

Said differently I would bet a coin that the resulting file contains the expected bytes, but that your further processing chokes on the control character.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) for `str.splitlines()` says it will split lines based on a number of line boundary types including `\x0c`. If you only want to explicitly split by \n then you could user `str.split('\n')` instead. However note that if your line ends with a `\n then you will end up with an empty group that you might want to drop  the last index if its empty string.

```py
data = '279304 9k=pN\n 279340 9k=PN\n 279376 9k<LN\n 279412 9k=\x0cN\n 279448 9k<4N\n'
lines = data.split('\n')
if lines[-1] == '':
    lines.pop()
print(lines)
for line in lines:
    print(line)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['279304 9k=pN', ' 279340 9k=PN', ' 279376 9k<LN', ' 279412 9k=\x0cN', ' 279448 9k<4N']
279304 9k=pN
 279340 9k=PN
 279376 9k<LN
 279412 9k=N
 279448 9k<4N
```

Answer (score 0):

```python
process = subprocess.run(['strings', '-o', main_exe], check=True, \
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
lines = [line.strip() for line in process.stdout.split('\n') if len(line) > 0]
```

Remove the call to `strip()` if you do want to keep that leading whitespace on every line

Answer (score 0):

Your problem arises from using the `splitlines` method of Unicode strings, which produces different results than the `splitlines` method of byte strings.

There is an issue for cpython for this problem, open since 2014: . [str.splitlines splitting on non-\r\n characters - Issue #66428 - python/cpython](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/66428).

Below I have added a portable `splitlines` function that uses the traditional ASCII line break characters for both Unicode and byte strings and works both under Python2 and Python3. A poor man's version for efficiency enthusiasts is also provided.

- In Python 2, type *str* is an 8-bit string and Unicode strings have type *unicode*.
- In Python 3, type *str* is a Unicode string and 8-bit strings have type *bytes*.

Although there is no actual difference in line splitting between Python 2 and Python 3 Unicode and 8-bit strings, when running vanilla code under Python 3, it is more likely to run into trouble with the extended [universal newlines](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html) approach for Unicode strings.

The following table shows which Python data type employs which splitting method.

| Split Method | Python 2 | Python 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ASCII | [str.splitlines](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) | [bytes.splitlines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.splitlines) |
| Unicode | [unicode.splitlines](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#unicode.splitlines) | [str.splitlines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines%20%20%20%20%20%20-) |

```
str_is_unicode = len('a\fa'.splitlines()) > 1

def splitlines(string): # ||:fnc:||
    r"""Portable definitive ASCII splitlines function.

    In Python 2, type :class:`str` is an 8-bit string and Unicode strings
    have type :class:`unicode`.

    In Python 3, type :class:`str` is a Unicode string and 8-bit strings
    have type :class:`bytes`.

    Although there is no actual difference in line splitting between
    Python 2 and Python 3 Unicode and 8-bit strings, when running
    vanilla code under Python 3, it is more likely to run into trouble
    with the extended `universal newlines`_ approach for Unicode
    strings.

    The following table shows which Python data type employs which
    splitting method.

    +--------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
    | Split Method | Python 2                  | Python 3                  |
    +==============+===========================+===========================+
    | ASCII        | `str.splitlines <ssl2_>`_ | `bytes.splitlines`_       |
    +--------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
    | Unicode      | `unicode.splitlines`_     | `str.splitlines <ssl3_>`_ |
    +--------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
    
    This function provides a portable and definitive method to apply
    ASCII `universal newlines`_ for line splitting. The reencoding is
    performed to take advantage of splitlines' `universal newlines`_
    aproach for Unix, DOS and Macintosh line endings.

    While the poor man's version of simply splitting on \\n might seem
    more performant, it falls short, when a mixture of Unix, DOS and
    Macintosh line endings are encountered. Just for reference, a
    general implementation is presented, which avoids some common
    pitfalls.

    >>> test_strings = (
    ...     "##\ftrail\n##\n\ndone\n\n\n",
    ...     "##\ftrail\n##\n\ndone\n\n\nxx",
    ...     "##\ftrail\n##\n\ndone\n\nx\n",
    ...     "##\ftrail\r##\r\rdone\r\r\r",
    ...     "##\ftrail\r\n##\r\n\r\ndone\r\n\r\n\r\n")

    The global variable :data:`str_is_unicode` determines portably,
    whether a :class:`str` object is a Unicode string.

    .. code-block:: sh

       str_is_unicode = len('a\fa'.splitlines()) > 1

    This allows to define some generic conversion functions:

    >>> if str_is_unicode:
    ...     make_native_str = lambda s, e=None: getattr(s, 'decode', lambda _e: s)(e or 'utf8')
    ...     make_uc_string = make_native_str
    ...     make_u8_string = lambda s, e=None: ((isinstance(s, str) and (s.encode(e or 'utf8'), 1)) or (s, 1))[0]
    ... else:
    ...     make_native_str = lambda s, e=None: ((isinstance(s, unicode) and (s.encode(e or 'utf8'), 1)) or (s, 1))[0]
    ...     make_u8_string =  make_native_str
    ...     make_uc_string = lambda s, e=None: ((not isinstance(s, unicode) and (s.decode('utf8'), 1)) or (s, 1))[0]

    for a protable doctest:

    >>> for test_string in test_strings:
    ...     print('--------------------')
    ...     print(repr(test_string))
    ...     print(repr([make_native_str(_l) for _l in splitlines(make_u8_string(test_string))]))
    ...     print(repr([make_native_str(_l) for _l in poor_mans_splitlines(make_u8_string(test_string))]))
    ...     print([make_native_str(_l) for _l in splitlines(make_uc_string(test_string))])
    ...     print([make_native_str(_l) for _l in poor_mans_splitlines(make_uc_string(test_string))])
    --------------------
    '##\x0ctrail\n##\n\ndone\n\n\n'
    ['##\x0ctrail', '##', '', 'done', '', '']
    ['##\x0ctrail', '##', '', 'done', '', '']
    ['##\x0ctrail', '##', '', 'done', '', '']
    ['##\x0ctrail', '##', '', 'done', '', '']
    --------------------
    '##\x0ctrail\n##\n\ndone\n\n\nxx'
    ['##\x0ctrail', '##', '', 'done', '', '', 'xx']
    ['##\x0ctrail', '##', '', 'done', '', '', 'xx']
    ['##\x0ctrail', '##', '', 'done', '', '', 'xx']
    ['##\x0ctrail', '##', '', 'done', '', '', 'xx']
    --------------------
    '##\x0ctrail\n##\n\ndone\n\nx\n'
    ['##\x0ctrail', '##', '', 'done', '', 'x']
    ['##\x0ctrail', '##', '', 'done', '', 'x']
    ['##\x0ctrail', '##', '', 'done', '', 'x']
    ['##\x0ctrail', '##', '', 'done', '', 'x']
    --------------------
    '##\x0ctrail\r##\r\rdone\r\r\r'
    ['##\x0ctrail', '##', '', 'done', '', '']
    ['##\x0ctrail', '##', '', 'done', '', '']
    ['##\x0ctrail', '##', '', 'done', '', '']
    ['##\x0ctrail', '##', '', 'done', '', '']
    --------------------
    '##\x0ctrail\r\n##\r\n\r\ndone\r\n\r\n\r\n'
    ['##\x0ctrail', '##', '', 'done', '', '']
    ['##\x0ctrail', '##', '', 'done', '', '']
    ['##\x0ctrail', '##', '', 'done', '', '']
    ['##\x0ctrail', '##', '', 'done', '', '']

    For further details see

    - Python 2: `5. Built-in Types - Python 2.7.18 documentation
      <https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html>`_
    - Python 3: `Built-in Types - Python 3.10.4 documentation
      <https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html>`_

    .. _`universal newlines`: https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html
    .. _`ssl2`: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines
    .. _`unicode.splitlines`: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#unicode.splitlines
    .. _`ssl3`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines      -
    .. _`bytes.splitlines`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.splitlines
    """
    if ((str_is_unicode and isinstance(string, str))
        or (not str_is_unicode and not isinstance(string, str))):
        # unicode string
        u8 = string.encode('utf8')
        lines = u8.splitlines()
        return [l.decode('utf8') for l in lines]
    # byte string
    return string.splitlines()

def poor_mans_splitlines(string):
    r"""
    """
    if str_is_unicode:
        native_uc_type = str
    else:
        native_uc_type = unicode
    if ((str_is_unicode and isinstance(string, str))
        or (not str_is_unicode and isinstance(string, native_uc_type))):
        # unicode string
        sep = '\r\n|\n'
        if not re.search(sep, string):
            sep = '\r'
        else:
            # |:info:|
            # if there is a single newline at the end, `$` matches that newline
            # if there are multiple newlines at the end, `$` matches before the last newline
            string += '\n'
        sep_end = '(' + sep + ')$'
        # prevent additional blank line at end
        string = re.sub(sep_end, '', string)
        return re.split(sep, string)
    # byte string
    return string.splitlines()
```