# Passing a string with spaces and newlines as command line argument python

Tags: python, command-line, newline, argv, sys

I am trying to pass a string with spaces and newlines in python script called `main.py` as a command line argument but am not sure if it is possible.

I am trying to pass the string `'5 2\n 3 3 2\n 1 1 2'` and have it appear within the script exactly like that. For this I am using `sys` and `argv` as such:

Command line:

```
python main.py "5 2\n 3 3 2\n 1 1 2"
```

Python script:

```
info_input = sys.argv[1]
```

However it appears that the output to this is a list with added escape characters in the newlines is:

```
['5 2\\n 3 3 2\\n 1 1 2']
```

Is it possible to pass this as an argument and have the output within the python appear as:

```
"5 2\n 3 3 2\n 1 1 2"
```

Many Thanks

EDIT

```py
print(info_input)

'5 2\n 3 3 2\n 1 1 2'

input_split = info_input.split(sep='\n')
print(input_split)

['5 2\\n 3 3 2\\n 1 1 2']
```

It hasn't split on the newlines here and is a list of the whole thing.

Comment: What are you looking to achieve? It's correct for the `\\n` to be there. Note that if you do `print(sys.argv[1])` the string is printed as you want.

Comment: My script uses the format `"5 2\n 3 3 2\n 1 1 2"` and splits the input by `\n` below which seems to fail if the escape characters are introduced. The output is also a list which is not in the string format that my script requires to process.

Comment: Do you want to upload an example of how that split you mention is failing? Can´t you use another separator that is not the newline character? The `\n` should be "splitable" anyway, maybe something like this can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/24237675/2923526 ?

Comment: (I mean the usage of  `splitlines`)

Comment: @ffigari Apologies for the delay. The splitlines method seems to have worked far better than splitting on the `\n` using the `sep` argument. However due to the escape character it still does not split anything and is the same as the edited version above.

Comment: I left an answer with some clarifications. In the future I suggest leaving a minimum working example of your problem. `working` in the sense that I could copy and paste the code to run it, since that makes it easier to debug the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of clarifications regarding this two points of your question

> I am trying to pass a string with spaces and newlines

> Is it possible to pass this as an arguement and have the output within the python appear as:

When you call your script with `python main.py "5 2\n 3 3 2\n 1 1 2"` you are not passing actual newline characters.
This is why you get `\\n` in your string, Python is escaping those `\n` since otherwise it would mean that your string **does have** newline chars.
You are confusing the representation of the string and the string itself. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr) about `repr` vs `str`.
When printing the string alone it is printed nicely, but when printing the list the escaped characters are shown, which explains why you get different results.

When you do:

```py
input_split = info_input.split(sep='\n')
print(input_split)
```

you are not actually splitting your string, since you string does not contain newline characters (`\n`), it contains escaped newline characters (`\\n`).
If you actually want to split your string in newlines you could do:

```py
input_split = info_input.split(sep='\\n')
print(input_split)
```

which outputs `['5 2', ' 3 3 2', ' 1 1 2']`.

---

That said, if your goal is to have **actual** newline characters in your program you can replace the escaped newlines with newlines:

```py
import sys

info_input = sys.argv[1]
info_input_with_escaped_newlines = info_input
print("info_input_with_escaped_newlines as string", info_input_with_escaped_newlines)
print("info_input_with_escaped_newlines as list", [info_input_with_escaped_newlines])

info_input_with_newlines = info_input.replace('\\n', '\n')
print("info_input_with_newlines as string", info_input_with_newlines)
print("info_input_with_newlines as list", [info_input_with_newlines])
```

which outputs

```sh
> python as.py "5 2\n 3 3 2\n 1 1 2"
info_input_with_escaped_newlines as string 5 2\n 3 3 2\n 1 1 2
info_input_with_escaped_newlines as list ['5 2\\n 3 3 2\\n 1 1 2']
info_input_with_newlines as string 5 2
 3 3 2
 1 1 2
info_input_with_newlines as list ['5 2\n 3 3 2\n 1 1 2']
```

Notice how now `split` **does split** the string:

```py
import sys

info_input = sys.argv[1].replace('\\n', '\n').split(sep='\n')
print(info_input)
```

which outputs:

```sh
python as.py "5 2\n 3 3 2\n 1 1 2"
['5 2', ' 3 3 2', ' 1 1 2']
```

Comment: Really good answer and explained very well. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A possible bypass could be `string.replace()`. You could do `'5 2NL 3 3 2NL 1 1 2'` and then `info_input = sys.argv[1].replace("NL", "\n")`. This might be a temporary solution until you find something better.

Comment: Thanks for unfortuantly this won't work as I split by `\n` further down in the script.