# Telethon text message new line

Tags: newline, telethon

I'm using telethon python3 library and I'm a bit stuck on this issue:

```
client = TelegramClient(session, api_id, api_hash).start()
client.send_message(recipient, string_message)
```

I try to split the message into multiple lines but I'm not able to find what char (or combination of chars) should be used for that. (for example `**text**` will make **text**, `__text__` will make  *text*, etc)

Obviously \n is not working. I found some ideas about inserting the `chr(10)` as new line mark in the `string_message` but I had no success with it.

Comment: \n\n?  What does \n do? (Do you have a quoting error with the \)

Comment: Actually I guess is more like a python interpretation of the string passed as argument in `client.send_message(str(sys.argv[1]), sys.argv[2])`. If i use it directly in the code with a hardcoded string like `client.send_message(str(sys.argv[1]), "line1\nline2")` it will send the message as expected, with two lines.

Comment: I got the expected result after reading `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65005261/passing-a-string-with-spaces-and-newlines-as-command-line-argument-python`  and using my own `delimiter` in the passed string (sys.argv) and replacing the delimiter in the code at runtime with `\n` just prior to passing the variable to telethon client.

Comment: @tethis welcome to StackOverflow. If you solved the problem, you can also answer your own question and marked it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

(answering my own question here):
I got the expected result after reading `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65005261/passing-a-string-with-spaces-and-newlines-as-command-line-argument-python` and using my own delimiter in the passed string (sys.argv) and replacing the delimiter in the code at runtime with `\n` just prior to passing the variable to telethon client.

- In my initial question I was passing the message as argument to a python script and inside the script the content of sys.argv was again cast/converted  to string (`str(sys.argv[x])`) and most probably this was breaking the `\n` formatting*