# How to display image and text at the same time in python (like SanctuaryRPG)?

Tags: python, pygame

So, I'm pretty new to python, but I'm currently coding a text-adventure game. I was wondering how I would be able to display the text at the bottom of the screen while an ASCII image is displayed on top, just like [SanctuaryRPG](https://www.sanctuaryrpg.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so basically, you want to print an **ASCII** image with text. This shouldn't be too difficult.

Firstly, set the ASCII image to a variable. For example:

```py
img = '''
                 __,__
        .--.  .-"     "-.  .--.
       / .. \/  .-. .-.  \/ .. \
      | |  '|  /   Y   \  |'  | |
      | \   \  \ 0 | 0 /  /   / |
       \ '- ,\.-"`` ``"-./, -' /
        `'-' /_   ^ ^   _\ '-'`
        .--'|  \._   _./  |'--. 
      /`    \   \ `~` /   /    `\
     /       '._ '---' _.'       \
    /           '~---~'   |       \
   /        _.             \       \
  /   .'-./`/        .'~'-.|\       \
 /   /    `\:       /      `\'.      \
/   |       ;      |         '.`;    /
\   \       ;      \           \/   /
 '.  \      ;       \       \   `  /
   '._'.     \       '.      |   ;/_
    /__>     '.       \_ _ _/   ,  '--.
   .'   '.   .-~~~~~-. /     |--'`~~-.  \
  // / .---'/  .-~~-._/ / / /---..__.'  /
 ((_(_/    /  /      (_(_(_(---.__    .'
           | |     _              `~~`
           | |     \'.
            \ '....' |
             '.,___.'
'''
```

Next, set the text you want to print out to another variable.

```py
text = "Do you want to say hi to the monkey?"
```

Finally, print the two like this:

```py
print(img)
print(text)
```

OR:

```py
print(img + "\n\n" + text)
```

`\n` Just means a new line.

Answer (score 0):

To do the same as in SanctuaryRPG with Pygame, you need to use a font where each character is the same width (e.g. Courier):

```py
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Courier", text_height)
```

Split the text into lines with `splitlines()` (see [How to split a python string on new line characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24237524/how-to-split-a-python-string-on-new-line-characters)):

```py
img_text = img.splitlines()
```

Render the text line by line in a loop:

```py
for i, line in enumerate(img_text):
    text_surf = font.render(line, True, (255, 255, 0))
    window.blit(text_surf, (50, 20 + i * text_height))
```

Use the following function:

```py
def renderTextImage(surf, font, text, x, y, color):
    img_text = text.splitlines()
    for i, line in enumerate(img_text):
        text_surf = font.render(line, True, color)
        surf.blit(text_surf, (x, y + i * text_height))
```

---

Minimal example:

<kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-AsciiTextImage](https://replit.com/@Rabbid76/PyGame-AsciiTextImage#main.py)</kbd>

[image]

```py
import pygame

img_text = r'''
                 __,__
        .--.  .-"     "-.  .--.
       / .. \/  .-. .-.  \/ .. \
      | |  '|  /   Y   \  |'  | |
      | \   \  \ 0 | 0 /  /   / |
       \ '- ,\.-"`` ``"-./, -' /
        `'-' /_   ^ ^   _\ '-'`
        .--'|  \._   _./  |'--. 
      /`    \   \ `~` /   /    `\
     /       '._ '---' _.'       \
    /           '~---~'   |       \
   /        _.             \       \
  /   .'-./`/        .'~'-.|\       \
 /   /    `\:       /      `\'.      \
/   |       ;      |         '.`;    /
\   \       ;      \           \/   /
 '.  \      ;       \       \   `  /
   '._'.     \       '.      |   ;/_
    /__>     '.       \_ _ _/   ,  '--.
   .'   '.   .-~~~~~-. /     |--'`~~-.  \
  // / .---'/  .-~~-._/ / / /---..__.'  /
 ((_(_/    /  /      (_(_(_(---.__    .'
           | |     _              `~~`
           | |     \'.
            \ '....' |
             '.,___.'
'''

def renderTextImage(surf, font, text, x, y, color):
    img_text = text.splitlines()
    for i, line in enumerate(img_text):
        text_surf = font.render(line, True, color)
        surf.blit(text_surf, (x, y + i * text_height))

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

text_height = 16 
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Courier", text_height)

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False          

    window.fill(0)
    renderTextImage(window, font, img_text, 50, 20, (255, 255, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```