# How to Create Spark or Pandas Dataframe from str output in Apache Spark on Databricks

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have assigned the variable "myoutput" to a string as follows

myoutput = result.content

myoutput is as follows:

```
Out[10]: 'Company A Invoice\nInvoice For:\nAddress:\n567 Main St.\nRedmond, WA\n555-555-5555\nBilbo Baggins\n123 Hobbit Lane\nRedmond, WA\n555-555-5555\nSubtotal: 300.00\nTax: 30.00\nTip: 100.00\nTotal: 430.00\nSignature: ____Bilbo Baggins__________\nItem\nQuantity\nPrice\nA\n1\n10.99\nB\n2\n14.67\nC\n4\n15.66\nD\n1\n12.00\nE\n4\n10.00\nF\n6\n12.00\nG\n8\n22.00'
```

I would like to create a spark dataframe or a pandas dataframe from "myoutput".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 import pandas as pd
 str_output = 'Company A Invoice\nInvoice For:\nAddress:\n567 Main St.\nRedmond, WA\n555-555-5555\nBilbo Baggins\n123 Hobbit Lane\nRedmond, WA\n555-555-5555\nSubtotal: 300.00\nTax: 30.00\nTip: 100.00\nTotal: 430.00\nSignature: ____Bilbo Baggins__________\nItem\nQuantity\nPrice\nA\n1\n10.99\nB\n2\n14.67\nC\n4\n15.66\nD\n1\n12.00\nE\n4\n10.00\nF\n6\n12.00\nG\n8\n22.00'
 df_data = pd.DataFrame({'ColumnA':str_output.splitlines()})
 df_data
```

Reference:
[How to split a Python string on new line characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24237524/how-to-split-a-python-string-on-new-line-characters)

Comment: Ian, thanks for reaching. Surely, I wouldn't have to type out all of "'Company A Invoice\nInvoice For:\nAddress:\n567 Main St.\nRedmond, WA\n555-555-5555\nBilbo Baggins\n123 Hobbit Lane\nRedmond, WA\n555-555-5555\nSubtotal: 300.00\nTax: 30.00\nTip: 100.00\nTotal: 430.00\nSignature: ____Bilbo Baggins__________\nItem\nQuantity\nPrice\nA\n1\n10.99\nB\n2\n14.67\nC\n4\n15.66\nD\n1\n12.00\nE\n4\n10.00\nF\n6\n12.00\nG\n8\n22.00'"

Comment: What if i have a document with over a thousands lines??

Comment: Oh, I got it, you were just using your answer with the full text as an illustration. I did the following and it work just as well 
```import pandas as pd

df_data = pd.DataFrame({'ColumnA':mydf.splitlines()})
df_data```