# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'splitlines' when converting code to Pandas Dataframe using function splitlines()

Tags: python, pandas

I was given help with the splitlines() function which worked perfect on string output which wasn't seperated by page numbers, see [How to Create Spark or Pandas Dataframe from str output in Apache Spark on Databricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72424403/how-to-create-spark-or-pandas-dataframe-from-str-output-in-apache-spark-on-datab/72424564#72424564)

I am now using `str_output = result.pages` as opposed to `str_output = result.content`

Now, when I execute

```
df_data = pd.DataFrame({'ColumnA':str_output.splitlines()})
df_data
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'splitlines'
```

I think its because of the way that I'm using the splitlines function, but I'm not sure.

Any help appreciated

I should show the full code, see below:

```
import pandas as pd
from azure.ai.formrecognizer import DocumentAnalysisClient

# field_list = ["result.content"]

document_analysis_client = DocumentAnalysisClient(
endpoint=endpoint, credential=AzureKeyCredential(key)
)

for blob in container.list_blobs():
  blob_url = container_url + "/" + blob.name
  poller = document_analysis_client.begin_analyze_document_from_url(
            "prebuilt-read", blob_url)
  result = poller.result()
  print("Scanning " + blob.name + "...")
  print ("document contains", result.content)

myoutput = result.pages

df_data = pd.DataFrame({'RAWTEXT':myoutput.splitlines()})
df_data
```

As resuesting, a sample of the data is as follows:

Scanning 05Jul11 Raet Prelim.pdf...
document contains PRELIMINARY REPORT
RAET HOLDING B.V.
5 JULY 2011
1
RæT
CONTENTS
1 INVESTMENT PROPOSAL ............................................................................................................ 5
1.1 Background to business................................................................................................................ 5 1.2 Process ........................................................................................................................................ 6
1.2.1 Overview .............................................................................................................................. 6
1.2.2 Due Diligence ....................................................................................................................... 7
1.2.3 Banking / Financing .............................................................................................................. 8
1.2.4 Proposed Tactics / Recommendation .................................................................................... 8
1.3 Investment Overview .................................................................................................................... 9
1.3.1 Investment thesis .................................................................................................................. 9
1.3.2 Business Strengths ............................................................................................................... 9
1.3.3 Investment Case Returns .....................................................................................................11
1.4 Key judgment calls ......................................................................................................................12
1.5 Recommendation ........................................................................................................................18
2 MARKET AND BUSINESS

Comment: The issue is that you're expecting `str_output` to be a string, but it's actually a list. You probably want a for loop like `for page in result.pages:` and to use `page.splitlines()` rather than `str_output.splitlines()`.  Inserting a `print(type(str_output))` might also clarify things.

Comment: Hi Sarah, thanks so much for reaching out. I should point out that my coding skills aren't as advanced as your skills. I have updated the question with the fulll code. If you could show me where I ought to make the amendments that would be most helpful. Sorry for being lazy, but I need to produce some results quickly for my manager

Answer (score 0):

Here `str_output` is a list while `splitlines()` is a function for string objects. If you just pass `str_output` as a value in the dictionary you shouldn't face this error.

```
df_data = pd.DataFrame({'ColumnA':str_output.splitlines()})
```

If this doesn't help then please put a sample of the data in `str_output` in the question.

Comment: Zero, I did the following df_data = pd.DataFrame({'RAWTEXT':myoutput}) and I got the following output ```0 DocumentPage(kind=document, page_number=1, ang...
1 DocumentPage(kind=document, page_number=2, ang...```

Comment: Any further help much appreciated.

Comment: @Patterson Please add this to the question for more clarity.

Comment: Zero, I have added some sample output. Just so you, there are 45 pages in total for this particular document

Comment: Hi, did my sample help? Or make things worse?