# Why do I not recieve an error when running this script in IDLE?

Tags: python

I've written a short script to read from a file which contains information about articles from a blog. Each line in the file corresponds to one article, and the tab-separated columns hold information such as an article 'id', title and paragraph.

```
id  title   paragraph
1   Motorola prototypes from Frog   Some cool looking concepts for phones, watches etc
2   Digital everything  This new york times article talks about the willingness of consumers
3   E-mails banned at summer camps  E-mails compound feelings of homesickness in kids
4   Simple Multimedia Websites/e-mail   This is a sort of website/e-mail generation site
5   Campground wi-fi    Wi-fi is now on the list of amenities offered at many campgrounds
6   Fog screen  Literally, a screen made by projecting onto fog
```

This code splits the file by the '\n' so that each article is an element in a list:

```
# Open file and skip first line(headers)
file = open("RBArticlesTabClean.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
file.readline()
# Read and decode whole file
articlesFile = htmlcodes.decodeString(file.read()).lower()
# Split file into its lines
articlesFileList = articlesFile.split("\n")
```

To test that this is working and that the program is reading the file correctly, I iterate through the list of articles obtained, and print the whole thing out:

```
for each in articlesFileList:
    input(each)
```

When running this in IDLE, it works as expected, printing out each line (in lowercase) every time the user presses the enter key.

However, when the script is run through the command prompt, it fails after printing three articles, with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python\RBTrends\RBTrendsAnalysis.py", line 52, in <module>
    print(each)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp850.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2019' in position 89: character maps to <undefined>
```

I have two questions:

1) Why do I receive this error?

2) Why is there a difference between running the program in IDLE and in the command prompt?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode - character maps to <undefined>, print function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630288/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-character-maps-to-undefined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know IDLE is capable of displaying unicode characters, while command prompt cannot do anything better than plain old ascii. That is the reason you are encountering this error.

Comment: That makes sense. Slightly annoying though.. Personally, I'd rather that IDLE wasn't capable of displaying Unicode, just to keep consistency.

Comment: Haha! Unfortunately with new smileys/characters cropping up every other day, unicode can't be ignored. It's better to have a unicode IDE that way