# Python Unicode Does not support character U+25BE

Tags: python-3.x, unicode

A problem had been plaguing me all day where Python 3.4.1 keeps returning

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u25be' in position 1075: character maps to undefined

[Unicode](http://unicode.org/charts) shows that U+25BE is ▾ BLACK DOWN-POINTING SMALL TRIANGLE.

I have been trying to read a file that contains this little guy and no matter what I do it doesn't seem to work. Here is the relevant code:

```
whole = ""
f = open(src, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
        for l in f:
            whole += l
print(whole)
```

The print will throw the error above. I have tried encoding it to ASCII with:

```
l.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

and still nothing. Am I failing to decode the file wrong? If it helps, this is also a webpage, and using the `urllib.request` module yields the exact same result.

I'm using Windows 7 if that makes a difference.

Comment: What version of Python? Works for me in 3.4.0.

Comment: Yup, a real character: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25be/index.htm

Comment: I am running 3.4.1 on windows 7.

Comment: What line has the error? http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/1040873 implies that it's actually the `print(whole)`, since the console can't render that character.

Comment: And i am aware that it is a real character. My question is whether i am decoding it correctly or if there is a problem in some other way.

Comment: So this is an issue with the Eclipse console? I am using Eclipse to code.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630288/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-character-maps-to-undefined

Comment: Ah, that seems to have pointed me in the right direction. @Wooble, if you post something about the question you posted, that is what i used. I will give you the credit.

Comment: related: [Python, Unicode, and the Windows console](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5419/4279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are printing to the Windows console.  The Windows console does not default to (and has poor support for) UTF-8, but you can change the code page and try again:

```
C:\>chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001

C:\>py
Python 3.3.0 (v3.3.0:bd8afb90ebf2, Sep 29 2012, 10:57:17) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print('\u25be')
▾

>>> import unicodedata as ud
>>> ud.name('\u25be')
'BLACK DOWN-POINTING SMALL TRIANGLE'
```

That displays the correct character for me on US English Windows using the `Consolas` console font, but not the `Lucida Console` or `Raster Fonts` fonts.  Make sure the font you are using supports the character.

Comment: [the support for multibyte codepages such as 65001 in Windows console is buggy](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31846091/4279). A better alternative is to [use `win-unicode-console` package](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30551552/4279)