# Python unicode console support under Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, python-3.x, unicode

I am trying to make an environment which allows printing of unicode characters both in Python 2.7 and 3.4, under Windows.

By using [Cmder](http://gooseberrycreative.com/cmder/) / [ConEmu](https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu) as a terminal, UTF-8 is fully supported out of the box.

However, Python support isn't so simple.

### Python 3.3+

If I set `chcp 65001`, Python 3.3+ detects it and runs fine.

### Python 2.7

If I set `chcp 65001` it simply doesn't work at all.  Python produces an error line while IPython doesn't work at all.

Apparently, by specifying `set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8` both Python and IPython work and allows printing of **some** unicode characters.

For example I can do:

```
print u'\xc1'
```

but I cannot do

```
print u'\xc1\xc1'
```

which produces: `IOError: [Errno 0] Error`

Still, it's better than nothing, at least most Python 2.7 programs would run unmodified.

My question is that if I add

```
@chcp 65001 > nul
@set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8
```

to the end of `cmder/vendor/init.bat`, would that have any side-effects on Python 3.3+?

Also, is there any way to let unmodified Python scripts `print u'\xc1\xc1'` under Windows?

Comment: `b'\xc1'.decode('utf-8')` raise `UnicodeDecodeError`. What result do you expect? 1. print Unicode instead of bytestrings 2. don't change chcp; it just complicates things 3. [Use `win-unicode-console` on Python 3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30551552/4279) to print Unicode to Windows console. Test the [`development` branch of `win-unicode-console`](https://github.com/Drekin/win-unicode-console/tree/development) on Python 2.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian sorry, that was obviously my typo. I've fixed it as well as added the error message to `u'\xc1\xc1'`. I am looking for a way to let unmodified Python scripts work on Windows console, not for including additional modules.

Comment: @zsero: click the link in my previous comment. It provides solutions for **unmodified** scripts.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian ok, using the development branch of win-unicode-console *and* putting it in `sitecustomize.py` enables seamless unicode printing in Python 2 under windows. It needs to be in sitecustomize otherwise it breaks ipython.

Comment: if it works for you then you could [post your own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: I'll do it then. It'll take some time to write it all up.

Comment: Note that ConEmu solves the remaining problem with fonts. The console window managed by conhost.exe limits the choice of fonts based on the system locale and doesn't support fonts that mix half-width and full-width glyphs. This rigid design makes life difficult for people who need a mix of East-Asian and Western languages in a single window. So we need to recommend win-unicode-console + pyreadline + ConEmu to get something close to the default terminal environment in a modern Linux system.

Comment: win-unicode-console now supports also Python 2.

Comment: where are you setting
\@chcp 65001 > nul
\@set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8
etc...? environment?
Want to try to solve. I have utf8 prb with neovim myself. Thanks,