# displaying error message in a non latin language in django form

Tags: python, django, forms, utf-8

I've already read a couple of questions regarding this issue but the solutions didn't work, forgive me if I've implemented them incorrectly.

basiclly i'm customizing the error that the django form displays

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')
    error_messages = {
        'username': {
            'unique': u"שם המשתמש שבחרת כבר קיים במערכת, נסה שם אחר",
        },
    }
```

I'm receiving the following error:

```
'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 60-61: character maps to <undefined>
```

I've added these lines to the top as suggested, still doesn't work:

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

any thoughts as to why it's not working?

Edit:

Ok i'm officaly tearing my hair out trying to fix this, all I want to do is display validation errors in heberew (my website is in hebrew) I've tried everything, I either get this error:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for %=: 'bytes' and 'dict'
```

or this one:

```
'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u05d0' in position 60: character maps to <undefined>
```

I need some help, please.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/q/14630288/263989

Comment: Are you using python2.x or python3.x?