# How to change encoding of a byte object in python 3?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, encoding, character-encoding

I wrote a program to scraping the web to get a json subtitle. that json is in Persian language. I used decode("utf-8") but my character is code.
what should I do?

My python is 3.4 and my OS is windows8, this is my code:

```
>>> import urllib.request as urllib2
>>> print(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.ted.com/talks/subtitles/id/667/lang/fa').read().decode("utf-8"))

{"captions":[{"duration":4000,"content":"\u0627\u0645\u0631\u0648\u0632\u0647 \u062a\u0645\u0627\u0645 \u0628\u0646\u0627\u0647\u0627 \u06cc\u06a9 \u0686\u06cc\u0632 \u0645\u0634\u062a\u0631\u06a9 \u062f\u0627\u0631\u0646\u062f.","startOfParagraph"...
```

The first row is this:
[image]

I use this way to write my string to a file but problem is exists yet:

```
with open('D:\\result.json', 'w') as fid:
    fid.write(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.ted.com/talks/subtitles/id/667/lang/fa').read().decode("utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have JSON there, with the Arabic characters escaped as [permitted by RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159.html#page-8).  You need to parse it with [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) in order to undo the escaping.  Once you've done that, you should be able to extract the "contents" value and print that (to a file, since Windows [can't always display Unicode properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630288/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-character-maps-to-undefined?lq=1) at the console).  Something like this:

```
>>> import urllib.request as urllib2
>>> result = json.loads(urllib2.urlopen('...').read().decode('utf8'))
>>> with open('example.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
...     print(result['captions'][0]['content'], file=f)
```

You should then be able to open example.txt with your editor of choice.  If it displays incorrectly, be sure to set the encoding to UTF-8.