# VS2015 + Python 3.4 File IO

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to self teach python by writing a quick script using Visual Studio 2015 and Python 3.4 to parse an Recuva output log file.

> Starting Point Promo 2013 - Compilation-HD.mp4                15020953
>   M:\Videos For Future Use\

Note the input file has multiple spaces between the filename, filesize and output path.

```
import os
import re

fileName = os.path.join( "C:\\", "Users", "temp", "Downloads", "deleted_files.txt" )

pattern = r"""
    (.*)
    \s{2,}
    \d+
    \s{2,}
    (.*)
"""

regex = re.compile( pattern, re.X )

try:
    with open( fileName ) as inputFile:
        # Loop over lines and extract variables of interest
        for line in inputFile:
            print( line )
            match_obj = regex.match( line )

            if match_obj: # pattern matched
                name = match_obj.group( 1 ) # group 1 is the first object
                directory = match_obj.group( 2 )
                print( name + "=>" + directory )
            else:
                print( "Line not matched: " + line )

        inputFile.close()
except (OSError, IOError) as err:
    raise IOError( "%s: %s" % (fileName, err.strerror))
```

Each time I run the code, I get an error on print( line ) and the debugger in VS2015 only shows newlines. Am I missing something in my file opening and read operation? Be kind, this is my first python script!

The error message I get back is *ÿþ-'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xfe' in position 1: character maps to*

EDIT (Updated Trial):
I receive the same error message if I run the script from the command line:

> File "RecuvaRenamer.py", line 21 in  
>      print( line )
>   File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 19, in encode
>      return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
>   UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xfe' in position 1 character maps to

Comment: What error? There's nothing obviously wrong with the code up to that point.

Comment: Apologies, forgot to add the error:
ÿþ-'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xfe' in position 1: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: maybe this question can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630288/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-character-maps-to-undefined

Comment: @KristianDamian that is the basic issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, nevermind. Nothing wrong with the code. The input file was not encoded in UTF-8. Converted input to UTF-8 format and the file "almost" parses correctly.