# 'Charmap' codec can't encode character (Unicode Serbian Latin)

Tags: python-3.x, encode

I did transfer from Linux to Windows, and i use Python3.
On Linux i could use unicode characters "š đ č ć ž" without any import or something now on windows i have this error when printing.

```
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0] UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0161' in position 62: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: Linux consoles default to utf-8 encoding, but the Windows console does not. I guess [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32176732/1292641) would help you most. See also this [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14630288/1292641).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"chcp 65001" typed in console solved problem and console font set to lucida