# How to print to a file a string with diacritics?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, utf-8

I have a word in Polish as a string variable which I need to print to a file:

```
# coding: utf-8

a = 'ilośc'
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    print(a, file=f)
```

This throws

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/scratches/scratch_3.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(a, file=f)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u015b' in position 3: character maps to <undefined>
```

Looking for existing answers ([with `.decode("utf-8")`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/606199/903011), or [with `.encode("utf-8")`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16120218/903011)) and trying various incantations I finally managed the file to be created.

Unfortunately what was written was `b'ilośc'`and not `ilośc`. When I tried to decode that before printing to the file, I got back to the initial error and the same traceback.

**How to write a `str` containing diacritics to a file so that it is a string and not a bytes representation?**

Comment: What Python version are you using? Encoding in Python 2.x is a pain...

Comment: @linusg You clearly see Python34 in the question

Comment: @user312016 Sorry, haven't seen!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traceback says that you are trying to save `'ś'` (`'\u015b'`)  character using `cp1252` encoding (the default is `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`—your Windows ANSI code page) that can't represent this Unicode character (there more than a million Unicode characters and cp1252 is a single-byte encoding that can represent only 256 characters).

Use a character encoding that can represent the desired characters:

```
with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-16') as file:
    print('ilośc', file=file)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = 'ilośc'
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(a)
```

You can even write to the file using the binary mode:

```
a = 'ilośc'
with open('test.txt', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(a.encode())
```