# Unicode Error for list object in Python

Tags: python, list, unicode

I ran into some Unicode errors in Python trying to print some strings and I solved most of it using the following code from the second bullet point of the answer given in the following post:
[UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode - character maps to <undefined>, print function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630288/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-character-maps-to-undefined)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys

print sys.stdout.encoding
print u"Stöcker".encode(sys.stdout.encoding, errors='replace')
print u"Стоескер".encode(sys.stdout.encoding, errors='replace')
```

However, I get an error while trying to use this on a list object. It gives me an error that the list does not have the attribute "encode".

Does someone have a clean solution to get around this?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: apply `encode()` to list items, not the list itself

Comment: please add the output you get (the error text) and your python version. Works here...

Comment: _'''It gives me an error that the list does not have the attribute "encode".'''_ That's because `list` does not have an `encode` method, that is a [method on a `str` or `unicode`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode)

Comment: what do you expect to happen if you did `[1,2,3].encode(...)`? Encode only makes sense to happen on a string, not a list.  If you want to encode each element then do that: `for i,item in enumerate(my_list): my_list[i] = item.encode(...)` or make a new list with encoded items with list comprehension: `[item.encode(...) for item in my_list]`

Answer (score 0):

When you print a list, the routines that do the printing will take non-string objects and call their `__str__` method to convert them to a string. But you are trying to call the `decode` method of a non-string object, and non-string objects don't have a `decode` method.

One way around this is to apply the `unicode` function to the list and then call the resulting string's `decode` method.

```
print unicode([u"Stöcker", u"Стоескер"]).encode(
               sys.stdout.encoding, errors='replace')
```

This should work with most objects.