# Can't encode Python list / Fail to write

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, encode

I've scratched my head for hours on this. Upon research it looks like I can't output something that's not encoded. I've tried pretty much everything. I've tried re-encoding linees, formatted, item, final_data. None of this worked. I've looked at probably every single SOF article on this issue and I have found nothing. It's very weird.

So I have:

```
for item in final_data:
    export = open(finalanswer , 'w')
    linees = item.text.encode('utf-8')
    formatted = linees.decode().split('00000')
    linees = item.text.encode('utf-8')
    export.write("\n".join(map(lambda x: str(x), final_data)) + "\n")
    export.close
    print("Complete. Bye")
```

Here's the error that this fetched back, not sure why this is not working...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Scripts\Python\Autorunner.py", line 152, in <module>
export.write("\n".join(map(lambda x: str(x), final_data)) + "\n")
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 85234-85238: character maps to <undefined>
```

Would someone possibly be able to help?

Comment: Could you provide some sample input?

Comment: you appear to be writing `final_data` for every `item in final_data`. Did you mean to write out `formatted`?

Comment: Tried writing out formatted, but then I got this error:

Comment: Same error, actually.

Comment: Sample input:
 [ _vbaaggregate_temp_1414455000] ', ' [ _vbaaggregate_temp_1414476600] ', ' [ _vbaaggregate_temp_1414487400] ', ' [ _vbaaggregate_temp_1414491000] ', ' [ _vbaaggregate_temp_1414494600] ', ' [ _vbaccess] ', ' [ _vbaction] ', ' [ _vbactivitystream] ', ' [ _vbactivitystreamtype] ', ' [ _vbad] ', ' [ _vbadcriteria]

Comment: Update: Tried writing out for every item in formatted. Same error.

Comment: @RyanDavis that's not a usable form of input

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630288/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-character-maps-to-undefined; note the uprint function.