# content missing when a file is written into another file Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, file-io, python-sip

Im an entry level Python developer working on a requirement where I need to merge so many text files in forder A into one file in Folder B. I wrote the below code which is working but its not writing the entire content from files in folder A.

```
 import os
 a = open(r"C:\temp\datsOutput\New folder\output.txt", "w")
 path = r'C:\temp\dats'
 for filename in os.listdir(path):
     fullPath = path+"\\"+filename
     with open(fullPath,'r',encoding="utf_8_sig", errors="ignore") as ins:
            for line in ins:
                 a.write(line)
```

the around 6000 lines from the below line are missing.

```
 ROUT:=  996.6mm
         ANGL:=  95degree
         ORRF:=  =0/0
       TMRREF:=  =0/0
       REPCOU:=  0
    END
    NEW CYLINDER 26 of SUBEQUIPMENT /FA-3101/MAIN_M1_DAVIT
           NAME:=  =805324448/24319
           TYPE:=  CYLI
           LOCK:=  false
          OWNER:=  /FA-3101/MAIN_M1_DAVIT
           PURP:=  unset
            POS:=  W 537.345mm S 46.083mm U 0mm
            ORI:=  Y is S and Z is U
           LEVE:=  0 10
           OBST:=  2
           DIAM:=  76.2mm
           HEIG:=  304.8mm
           ORRF:=  =0/0
         TMRREF:=  =0/0
         REPCOU:=  0
       :PSTATUS:=  unset
    END
    NEW CYLINDER 27 of SUBEQUIPMENT /FA-3101/MAIN_M1_DAVIT
           NAME:=  =805324448/24320
           TYPE:=  CYLI
           LOCK:=  false
          OWNER:=  /FA-3101/MAIN_M1_DAVIT
           PURP:=  unset
            POS:=  W 537.345mm S 46.083mm U 6.125mm
            ORI:=  Y is S and Z is U
           LEVE:=  0 10
           OBST:=  2
```

for testing purpose the folder A now has only one file which has 204034 lines and the script has written 203799 lines, is it a problem of encoding? I simply cant go any direction from here any small help is greatly appreciated and saves my job, thank you

Comment: Try to compare both files and check what is coming extra.

Comment: Hi Dinesh Thanks for the response the below are missingROUT:=  996.6mm
             ANGL:=  95degree
             ORRF:=  =0/0
           TMRREF:=  =0/0
           REPCOU:=  0
        END
        NEW CYLINDER 26 of SUBEQUIPMENT /FA-3101/MAIN_M1_DAVIT
               NAME:=  =805324448/24319
               TYPE:=  CYLI
               LOCK:=  false
              OWNER:=  /FA-3101/MAIN_M1_DAVIT
               PURP:=  unset
                POS:=  W 537.345mm S 46.083mm U 0mm
                ORI:=  Y is S and Z is U
               LEVE:IN_M1_DAVIT

Comment: Can you please post the missing lines in the question (by editing) so that it is more clear (like spaces and new lines). Also, have you tried using `utf-8`? Does the same issue occur?

Comment: I upddated the question to reflect the missing lines, I havent tried using UTF-8 will try it now

Comment: When I try UTF-8 i am getting the below error                            
                                                                                                    
                                         Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\chaitanyavardhan\Desktop\datsMerge.py", line 8, in <module>
    a.write(line)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ufeff' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: The lines you have posted are getting copied in my case, irrespective of encoding. Do you do a.close() at the end? Also, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630288/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-character-maps-to-undefined

Comment: when i use UTF-8 its not writing any lines into the File B, unlike before which has written 203799 lines into fileB

Comment: no I havent written a.close at the end, was that causing the problem?

Comment: I wrote a.close at the end, still the same