# Woocommerce Python API

Tags: python, python-2.7, woocommerce

I am looking to write a script that will export  orders from a specific date and export them into a word document. I am using Python 2.7 to query the Woocommerce API.

I am only interested in one attribute from the order which is: the line_items meta data - message.

Here is my current Python code to extract the message from one specific order:

```
from woocommerce import API
import json   
from docx import Document


wcapi = API(
    url="xxxxxxxx",
    consumer_key="xxxxxx",
    consumer_secret="xxxxxxx",
    wp_api=True,
    version="wc/v2",
    query_string_auth=True 
)



json_data = (wcapi.get("orders/383").json())

json_parsed = json.dumps(json_data)


new = json_parsed.decode("utf-8")
new1 = json.loads(new)

new2 = (new1['line_items'][0]['meta_data'])

print  new2
```

And this is the output:

> [{u'key': u'Message', u'id': 475, u'value': u'Dear [TES TSTE STST EST\r\n\r\nIt has been very bu
>   e. The elves have been working around the clock to make sure the toys are ready to deliver to al
>   s. Rudolph and his fellow reindeer are getting ready for the long journey ahead, and I\u2019m si
>   riting this letter and enjoying a lovely mince pie.\r\n\r\nI am writing to let you know that you
>   aved this year and have made it onto my good child list. \r\n\r\nI am very proud of you, and as
>   u2019d like to get you something extra-special for Christmas this year. \r\n\r\nI\u2019ll be vis
>   n, keep up the good work. this is ss a gadfh\r\n\r\nMerry Christmas!\r\nFrom Santa Claus'}]

As you can see the output isn't correct.

1. How do I only pull in the contents of the message only - everything from 'Dear' onwards.
2. How do I format the output correctly? There looks to be lots of odd codes where there is meant to be a new paragraph or punctuation.
3. How would I export the message from Python and save in a word doc?

Thanks in advance
Nick

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a dictionary, this would be: 
    new2[0]['value']

Comment: Where would I enter the above? Like this :new2 = (new2[0]['value'])

Comment: for example: new2 = (new1['line_items'][0]['meta_data'][0]['value'])

Comment: I tried the above and got the following error:  UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 276: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630288/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-character-maps-to-undefined