# Storing a large list into a text file

Tags: python, list

I have a large list which consist of approx **47234** English sentences and there are some **emojis** in my list. i will use this list to make chatbot, but i want to know that in which format **e.g txt or csv or etc** that i should store my list in a file, but the problem is that list also contains **emojis**.
What should i do, in which format that i can easily retrieve?

Here is some content of my list:

```
['hi there', 'Hello!', 'Hi! How are you?', 'Not bad! And You?',
 "I'm doing well. Just got engaged to my high school sweetheart.",
 'Wowowowow! Congratulations! Is she pretty?', 
"She 's pretty cute. She invited me to dinner tonight. ",
 'Cool! Have a good time you both! And what is your hobby?',
 'I love music! I love Taylor swift. ']
```

I have tried this:

```
with open("file.txt", 'w') as output:
    for sentence in sentences:
        output.write(str(sentence) + '\n')
```

This code give the error message:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f642' in position 54: character maps to <undefined>
```

It seems that this error message is due to emojis.

As i mentioned the length of the list is **47324** so using for loop is not a feasible solution.

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: 47324 is very small... What is the problem with what you currently do?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille which file format is better in my case if i want to retrieve a list as it is, as i storing.

Comment: @AS2 I would say JSON is likely the easiest

Comment: @jordanm but the structure of my data is very simple, it is just text messages

Comment: This question needs more focus and detail. *Exactly* why is the for loop a problem?

Comment: How did your attempt to store it as a plain text file fail?

Comment: If none of the strings contain newlines, carriage returns, or other control characters (which they shouldn't), the current method should work fine. JSON or other formats would work of course, but would add a bit of overhead. What's the problem with your current method?

Comment: @wjandrea i have edited my post and included error message

Comment: Related? [UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode - character maps to <undefined>, print function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14630288/4518341), [Python, Unicode, and the Windows console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5419/4518341)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json) is the simplest way:

```
import json

data = ['hi there', 'Hello!', 'Hi! How are you?', 'Not bad! And You?',
 "I'm doing well. Just got engaged to my high school sweetheart.",
 'Wowowowow! Congratulations! Is she pretty?', 
"She 's pretty cute. She invited me to dinner tonight. ",
 'Cool! Have a good time you both! And what is your hobby?',
 'I love music! I love Taylor swift. ']

# writing the data to file
with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)

# reading the data
with open('data.json') as f:
    read_data = json.load(f)

print(read_data)
# ['Hi there', 'Hello!', 'Hi! How are you?', 'Not bad! And You?', 
#  "I'm doing well. Just got engaged to my high school sweetheart.", 
#  'Wowowowow! Congratulations! Is she pretty?',
#  "She 's pretty cute. She invited me to dinner tonight. ", 
#  'Cool! Have a good time you both! And what is your hobby?', 
#  'I love music! I love Taylor swift. ']
```

Comment: yes! json works well as i expected Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I've modified your code to include `utf-8` encoding when writing to `file.txt`

```
sentences = ['hi there', 'Hello!', 'Hi! How are you?', 'Not bad! And You?',
 "I'm doing well. Just got engaged to my high school sweetheart.",
 'Wowowowow! Congratulations! Is she pretty?', "She 's pretty cute. She invited me to dinner tonight. ",
 'Cool! Have a good time you both! And what is your hobby?', 'I love music! I love Taylor swift. ']

with open("file.txt", 'w', encoding="utf-8") as output:
    for sentence in sentences:
        output.write(str(sentence) + '\n')
```