# Python : How do I write to a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted to add extra functionality to [wiki-bot](https://github.com/fast-and-curious-1910/wiki-bot.git) by adding a way for it to write to file and print it at the same time so that the user can skip the long wait to copy all the information.
My code works with

```
print
```

but not with

```
f = open("output_from_wikibot.txt", "w")
f.write("Page content:\n", content, "\n")
f.write("Page title:", title, "\n")
f.write("Categories:", categories, "\n")
f.write("Links:", links, "\n")
f.write("References:", references, "\n")
f.write("Summary:", summary, "\n")
```

It gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
```

At first I thought "Oh that's easy, just take each one of them and put them in a different line" but of course, it did not work.

I am newbie to Python and Wikipedia API. I have done projects with PRAW, Discord.py, BeautifulSoup4

Comment: "just take each one of them and put them in a different line" and of course , It did not work " in how far did this not work?

Comment: Not at all @MisterMiyagi

Comment: String concate can be done using `+`, not `,` in Python

Comment: @Cid I don't think he expected `,` to do concatenation, he was just assuming it worked similar to `print()`.

Comment: @FastAndCurious And now what does "not at all mean"? Do you get an error, and if so which? Do you get no output in the file? Does something else happen?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Got the problem solved!

Answer (score 3):

As the error message says clearly, `write()` only takes one argument; it's not like `print()`, which allows you to give multiple arguments and they'll all be printed. If you want to write multiple strings in a single call, you have to concatenate them.

```
f.write("Page content:\n" + content + "\n")
```

or use string formatting:

```
f.write(f"Page content\n{content}\n")
```

Comment: Nope dosent work 
``` Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 38, in <module>
    f.write(f"Page content\n{content}\n")
  File "C:\Users\Palash\anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0101' in position 30: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630288/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-character-maps-to-undefined

Comment: If that doesn't help, you can find more similar posts by googling "python unicodeencodeerror charmap codec"

Comment: Saw that , did not think you i could implement it

Comment: Try: `f = open("output_from_wikibot.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")`

Comment: with open("output_from_wikibot.txt", "w" , encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write("Page content:\n" + content + "\n")
    f.write("Page title:" + title + "\n")
    f.write("Categories:" + categories + "\n")
    f.write("Links:" + links + "\n")
    f.write("References:" + references + "\n")
    f.write("Summary:" + summary + "\n")
Worked
Now i get 
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str

Answer (score 2):

When you write `f.write("Page content:\n", content, "\n")`, Python thinks you passed 3 arguments to the `write` method, because there are three elements separated by commas. `write` just needs the string you want to write to the file.
In Python, string concatenation is made with `+` operator.

Also I suggest you to use the `with` statement before opening the file. It will make sure the file will be closed when you get out of the scope.

```
with open("output_from_wikibot.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write("Page content:\n" + content + "\n")
    f.write("Page title:" + title + "\n")
    f.write("Categories:" + categories + "\n")
    f.write("Links:" + links + "\n")
    f.write("References:" + references + "\n")
    f.write("Summary:" + summary + "\n")
```

Comment: I get this error https://pastebin.com/raw/0ZaVHuZD

Comment: Try adding `encoding='utf-8'` in the `open` call like I did in the edit. Also, do `content`, `title` etc. variables are strings ?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is exactly as the error message states.
The API `f.write()` takes only one argument, it takes a single string, and writes it to a line in the file.

You will need to do string concatenation.

`f.write("Page content:\n" + content)`
[Google is your friend](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/writing-to-file-in-python/)