# function write in python for a json file

Tags: python, json, classification

I'm a beginner in python so I have this program where it classifies tweets into different categories (sport,sante, culture...) using keywords and I would like to copy-paste every line of the JSON file that belongs to a certain category into a file named text1
and I did the following :
but I guess I did it the wrong way since I keep receiving the same error
please any suggestion on how to solve this problem!

```py
import json
import mysql.connector
'''
python -m pip install unicode
'''

c = 0
n = 0


sportcount=0
religcount=0
santecount=0
educcount=0
cultcount=0
socicount=0
policount=0

covid = ['كوفيد','MEDECIN','كورونا','CORONA', 'COVID','VACCIN', 'PANDEMIE', 'CONFINEMENT', 'PANDEMIE', 'CHU', 'GEL','ﻣﺎﺳﻚ' ,'CHINA','ANTIVIRALES','LAVAGE DE MAINS','VIRUS','اﻟﺤﺮاﻙ','اﻟﺤﺠﺮ','CHLOROQUINE','FATIGUE','كماما','STAYSAFE','EPIDEMIE','STAYHOME','منظمة الصحة',' pas de prière']

sport=['مولودية','WORKOUT','بايرن','ارسنال','ليفربول','منتخب','تتويج','ميسي','PSG','FIFA', 'FOOT','FEKIR', 'BOUGER', 'DANSER', 'STADE','بونجاح','JOUEUR', 'COMPETION', 'SPORT', 'SALLE', 'SPONSOR', 'PISCINE', 'PUMA', 'GYM', 'TEN', 'MATCH', 'CHAMPION', 'BASKET', 'NOVAK', 'DJOKOVIC', 'MESSI', 'OLYMPIQUE']
religion=['ALLAH','المساجد','مصل','HAMDULILAH','المسلم','فتوى','لله','EID','الله','MOSQ','دين']
sante=['controle','إصاب','OXYGENE','بوناطيرو','حالات','مؤكد','IMMUNIT','CAS','صح','DOCTEUR','مخبر','حصيلة','صحة','أطباء','تسجل','FATIG','مستشف','HOPITAUX','سعال','لقاح','SOUCHES','MALADE','حصيلة','FUMEURS', 'DIABETE', 'EPIDEMIE', 'DEPISTAGE', 'SOIGNANT', 'INJECTION','GEL','SANTE', 'FIEVRE', 'KAWASAKI', 'RESPIRATOIRE', 'PATIENT', 'TEST', 'TRAITEMENT','فحص','كماما', 'CHU','منظمة الصحة', 'MEDECINE', 'POSITIF', 'PHARMACE', 'INFECTES', 'IMMUN', 'VACCIN', 'PFIZER', 'PCR', 'PANDÉM', 'PANADEMI', 'ÉPIDÉMI', 'EPIDEMIC', 'MASQUE', 'BAVETTE', 'MASK', 'MÉDICAL', 'MEDICAL', 'HÔPITAL', 'HOSPITAL', 'INFECT', 'TRANSMISSION', 'SURVIVANT', 'SURVIVORS', 'DIAGNOSTIC', 'DIAGNOSIS', 'SANTÉ', 'HEALTH', 'MÉDECIN', 'DOCTOR', 'MÉDICAMENT', 'MEDICIN', 'AMBULANCE', 'DÉPISTAGE', 'DEPISTAGE', 'STATISTI', 'MALAD', 'SICK', 'CONFIN', 'PROPAGATION', 'PRÉVENTION', 'PREVENTION', 'CONTAGION', 'SYMPT', 'MESUR', 'MEASUR', 'MICROB', 'WASH', 'ISOL']
education=['سنة','collaboration','bac','EDUC','ÉCOLE','PROF','بتدائي','تعليم','أساتذة','دراس','طلبة']
culture=['LIVRE', 'BOOK', 'SHOP', 'FILM', 'MOVIE', 'MUSIC', 'TV', 'VOYAGE', 'CINEMA', 'ART', 'BLOG', 'SONG']
social=['الشباب','TWITTER','تغريد','متابعة','SOCI','NETFLIX','YOUTUBE','JOURNAL','solde','liquidationy']
politique=['manifestation','AFFAIRE', 'PUBLIQUE', 'AMBASSADE', 'CIRCONSPECTION', 'CIVI', 'COMBINAISON', 'DÉMAGOGIE', 'DÉMOCRATIE', 'DIPLOMATE', 'ÉCONOMIE', 'ÉTAT', 'FÉDÉRALISME', 'GOUVERNEMENT', 'LEGATION', 'MACHIAVÉLIQUE', 'MACHIAVÉLISME', 'MANŒUVRIER', 'NÉGOCI', 'POLICE', 'POUVOIR', 'PRUDE', 'PUBLIC', 'STRATÉGIE', 'TRACTATION', 'RÉPUBLIQUE', 'SONDAGE', 'OPINION', 'PARLEMENT', 'CITO', 'DÉPUTÉ', 'DIRIGEANT', 'MAIRE', 'MINIST', 'SECRÉTAIRE', 'SÉNATEUR', 'CONSEILLER', 'MAIRE', 'COMMUNES', 'MEMBRE', 'DU', 'PARLEMENT', 'CONGRÈS', 'SÉNAT', 'PROTESTATION', 'PROCURATION', 'POUVOIR', 'FRAUDE','النفط','وزير','HOLLANDE','خدعة','تبون','الغلق','BORIS JOHNSON','وزار','رئيس','DROITS','مؤامرة','والي','TRUMP','GOUVERNEMEN', 'POLITI', 'OUYAHIA', 'ERAK', 'IRAK', 'REINE', 'MACRON', 'MINIST', 'AMBASSAD', 'MANIFEST', 'PRESIDENT', 'SELLAL', 'NATIONAL', 'مظاهر','MILITAIRE', 'DICTATEUR','اﻟﺤﺮاﻙ']

myJsonFile = open('tweet.json', encoding="utf-16")
resultat = open('texte.txt', 'w')
for line in myJsonFile:
    data = json.loads(line)
    c = c+1
    text = data['raw_text'].upper()
    tweet = any(ele in text for ele in covid )
    if tweet == True:
     n=n+1

     #print(str(n) + " the " +str(c)+" tweet---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
     in_sport = any(ele in text for ele in sport )
     if in_sport:
        data["cat"]='sport'
        resultat.write(line)
        sportcount=sportcount+1

        print(data)
     else :
        in_sante = any(ele in text for ele in sante )
        if in_sante :
            data["cat"]='sante'
            resultat.write(line)
            santecount=santecount+1

            print(data)
        else :
            in_politique = any(ele in text for ele in politique)
            if  in_politique:
                data["cat"]='politique'
                policount=policount+1
                resultat.write(line)
                print(data)
            else:
                in_culture = any(ele in text for ele in culture )
                if in_culture:
                    data["cat"]='culture'
                    cultcount=cultcount+1
                    resultat.write(line)
                    print(data)
                else:
                    in_religion = any(ele in text for ele in religion)
                    if in_religion:
                        data["cat"]='religion'
                        religcount=religcount+1
                        resultat.write(line)
                        print(data)
                    else:
                        in_education = any(ele in text for ele in education )
                        if in_education:
                            data["cat"]='education'
                            educcount=educcount+1
                            resultat.write(line)
                            print(data)
                        else:
                            in_social = any(ele in text for ele in social)
                            if in_social:
                                data["cat"]='social'
                                socicount=socicount+1
                                resultat.write(line)
                                print(data)
                            else:
                                print(" the tweet---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")




print("a partir de",c," le nombre de tweets concernant le covid sont ",n)
print("sport ",sportcount," sante ",santecount," politique ",policount," culture ",cultcount," religion ",religcount," education ",educcount,"social",socicount)
print("les tweets non classifies",n-(educcount+religcount+cultcount+policount+santecount+sportcount+socicount))
```

error:

```
  exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/NIHAD/PycharmProjects/pythonProject3/classification.py", line 51, in <module>
    resultat.write(line)
  File "C:\Users\NIHAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 451-454: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: how does your expected output look like?

Comment: I believe you need to specify an encoding on the output file.

Comment: I agree with @John, if you don't specify it, it's platform dependent. Try `resultat = open('texte.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-16")`.

Comment: Code in a question should be a [mre] -- the **shortest possible** code that generates your problem when run without changes. We don't want your whole program; instead, we want a program written with the sole purpose being to tersely and clearly recreate the problem you're asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a very simple case of fixing the encoding.

Your error says:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 451-454: character maps to <undefined>
```

If it does not have to be encoded in utf-16, try opening the json file like:

```
myJsonFile = open('tweet.json', encoding="utf-8")
```

and specifying the encoding in the result file:

```
resultat = open(file, 'w', encoding='utf-8')
```

You might get lucky and that will fix it!

It it doesn't fix it, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092833/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-characters) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630288/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-character-maps-to-undefined) are answers that go deeper into detail about diagnosing the problem and potential solutions:

[UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092833/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-characters)

Comment: If a question is too broad to write a comprehensive answer to, it should be closed (until revised to be more narrowly asked), not answered in part. Similarly, a duplicative question should be marked a duplicate of the prior instances (a user with gold-badge priviliges in a tag can make a list of multiple duplicates, for the case where there are several prior instances that answer the question in full when combined -- questions can also be closed as Too Broad when this applies). In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), see the section _Answer Well-Asked Questions_.