# How to take the output of a print and write it in a file?

Tags: python

I am trying to take the output of the web scrap and put it in a 1 txt file  but it gives me an error saying

```py
'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u200a' in position 23130: character maps to <undefined>
  File "C:\Users\Web scrapper.py", line 12, in <module>
    f.write(y)
```

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pyperclip
x = input("Link you want to scrap from:")
url = x
page = urlopen(url)
html = page.read().decode("utf-8")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
y = str(soup.get_text())
print(y)
with open('Dogs.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(y)
```

Comment: What is the entire error message? Please [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: ok i added the full error message that i get

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode - character maps to <undefined>, print function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630288/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-character-maps-to-undefined)

Comment: i tried doing it it didnt fix it for some reason :/

Comment: You tried doing what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is opened with the `charmap` codec by default. You are trying to write a character to the file which the codec doesn't support - hence the error. To make sure this doesn't happen, open the file for writing with the same codec as you decoded the HTML content with. Like this:

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen

x = input("Link you want to scrap from:")
page = urlopen(url)
html = page.read().decode("utf-8")
print(html)
with open('Dogs.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(html)
```

Also, as @Code-Apprentice wrote, there's no need to use `BeautifulSoup` here.

Answer (score -1):

In this particular case, you can just do `f.write(html)`. There is no need to use `BeautifulSoup` or for the variable `y` since you are just taking the entire webpage.

Comment: i tried doing it but it gave me same error :/