# python in module of csv

Tags: python, csv, python-itertools

[image: here is the problem]

The charmap' codec is unable to encode the character 'u202f' in position 168, which maps to undefined> wr.writerows(unpacking).)

I don't know what the problem is; if someone already has this problem, he can help us.

Please, if anyone can assist me!

Comment: Don't post your code as an image

Answer (score 0):

you have to change the output encoding

```
import sys

print sys.stdout.encoding
print u"Stöcker".encode(sys.stdout.encoding, errors='replace')
print u"Стоескер".encode(sys.stdout.encoding, errors='replace')
```

for more [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630288/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-character-maps-to-undefined)