# Return form of 'get' request. Getting information in website which is written in json form

Tags: json, python-3.x, web

## My question

I tried many times to get information from url, In the website information is written in json form. And I found that 1,2,3 is wrong form.

what does request.get return?? and i wonder why 1, 2 and 3 does not work.

And how can I turn json in to dictionary form( not like fourth case)? I want to know other ways too. different from

```
response = response.json()
```

## My codes(1,2,3 Wrong and 4 is correct)

1.TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not Response

```
response = requests.get(URL)
response = json.loads(response)
```

2.TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not Response

```
response = requests.get(URL)
response = json.load(response)
```

3.AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'read'

```
response = requests.get(URL)
response = response.read()
```

4. correct one

```
response = requests.get(URL)
response = response.read()
```

Comment: You probably need to encode the JSON. Check this answer out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23049767/parsing-http-response-in-python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what does request.get return?

According to the [documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.get), it returns a [`requests.Response`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response) object.

> And how can I turn json in to dictionary form

What's wrong with `response = response.json()`?

Your attempts to use `json.load()` and `json.loads()` failed because you passed it a `Response` object, instead of a `str`, `bytes` or `bytearray`. Be sure to fully read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

`response.text` gives you a `str` of the response, which is what you are really after. `response.read()` raises an `AttributeError` because there is no `read()` method for `requests.Response` objects. Again, make sure you fully read the documentation.

This is what you want: `json.loads(response.text)`.