# Remove newline in python with urllib

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I am using Python 3.x. While using `urllib.request` to download the webpage, i am getting a lot of `\n` in between. I am trying to remove it using the methods given in the other threads of the forum, but i am not able to do so. I have used `strip()` function and the `replace()` function...but no luck! I am running this code on eclipse. Here is my code:

```
import urllib.request

#Downloading entire Web Document 
def download_page(a):
    opener = urllib.request.FancyURLopener({})
    try:
        open_url = opener.open(a)
        page = str(open_url.read())
        return page
    except:
        return""  
raw_html = download_page("http://www.zseries.in")
print("Raw HTML = " + raw_html)

#Remove line breaks
raw_html2 = raw_html.replace('\n', '')
print("Raw HTML2 = " + raw_html2)
```

I am not able to spot out the reason of getting a lot of `\n` in the `raw_html` variable.

Comment: Perhaps you're getting a `\r\n` instead of just `\n`? You would still see a new line if you just remove `\n`. Try to replace both.

Comment: I also ried `.replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '').replace('\t', '')` but it did not solve my problem!

Comment: i think they are literal `\n` characters.

Comment: try "".join(raw_html.split())

Comment: What happens if you print as hex? Is there a `char(13)` in the output? `' '.join(x.encode('hex') for x in raw_html2)`?

Comment: no these still does not solve the problem... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like they are literal `\n` characters , so i suggest you to do like this.

```
raw_html2 = raw_html.replace('\\n', '')
```

Comment: it cures only symptoms and even not all of them e.g., I bet there is spurious `b'` in the string, see [the explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27674228/4279).

Answer (score 8):

Your `download_page()` function corrupts the html (`str()` call) that is why you see `\n` (two characters `\` and `n`) in the output. Don't use `.replace()` or other similar solution, fix `download_page()` function instead:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

with urlopen("http://www.zseries.in") as response:
    html_content = response.read()
```

At this point `html_content` contains a `bytes` object. To get it as text, you need to know its character encoding e.g., to get it from `Content-Type` http header:

```
encoding = response.headers.get_content_charset('utf-8')
html_text = html_content.decode(encoding)
```

See [A good way to get the charset/encoding of an HTTP response in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14592762/4279).

if the server doesn't pass charset in `Content-Type` header then there are [complex rules to figure out the character encoding in html5 document](https://blog.whatwg.org/the-road-to-html-5-character-encoding) e.g., it may be specified inside html document: `<meta charset="utf-8">` (you would need an html parser to get it).

If you read the html correctly then you shouldn't see literal characters `\n` in the page.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source you've downloaded, the `\n` escape sequences you're trying to `replace()` are actually escaped themselves: `\\n`. Try this instead:

```
import urllib.request

def download_page(a):
    opener = urllib.request.FancyURLopener({})
    open_url = opener.open(a)
    page = str(open_url.read()).replace('\\n', '')
    return page
```

I removed the `try`/`except` clause because generic `except` statements without targeting a specific exception (or class of exceptions) are generally bad. If it fails, you have no idea why.

Comment: thank you for your answer..! it worked for me! I also replaced the function as suggested by you!

Comment: it is a mistake to call `str()` here, see [the explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27674228/4279).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I know, I was just trying to keep the OP's code as close to the original as possible. (Yes, I did remove the try/except clauses, but that really bugged me). Personally, I'd rewrite the whole thing to use `requests`, and make a 1-liner out of it, but you deal with what you're dealt :)