# Httpresponse to string python

Tags: python, string, httpresponse, python-3.5

I am trying to display a webpage, but since it does not view the object as a string, it does not properly display newlines (it displays `\n`). How can I make a result a string properly as this does not seem to be working. Thanks!

```
result = urllib.request.urlopen(requesturl).read()
return str(result)
```

Comment: The question is not clear. The fact that it contains `\n` does not make it an invalid string. Is this at all specific to `pyqt` or are you simply looking to print a single string broken up by new lines?

Comment: I want the \n character to actually print a new line, however since the type seems to be httpresponse, it prints the character \n instead of a new line.

Answer (score 4):

As explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27674076/remove-newline-in-python-with-urllib), you need to handle the character encoding of the response you have from the Content-Type. urllib provides a handy way to get at this from the headers using the get_content_charset method.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

with urlopen(request_url) as response:
  html_response = response.read()
  encoding = response.headers.get_content_charset('utf-8')
  decoded_html = html_response.decode(encoding)
  return decoded_html
```