# Fetch PowerShell script from GitHub and execute it

Tags: python, powershell, urllib2

Running into issues executing a PowerShell script from within Python.

The Python itself is simple, but it seems to be passing in `\n` when invoked and errors out.

```python
['powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File', '$Username = "test";\n$Password = "password";\n$URL
```

This is the code in full:

```python
import os
import subprocess
import urllib2
fetch = urllib2.urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/test')
script = fetch.read()
command = ['powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File', script]

print command   #<--- this is where I see the \n. 
#\n does not appear when I simply 'print script'
```

So I have two questions:

1. How do I correctly store the script as a variable without writing to disk while avoiding `\n`?
2. What is the correct way to invoke PowerShell from within Python so that it would run the script stored in `$script`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. How do I correctly store the script as a variable without writing to disk while avoiding `\n`?

This question is essentially a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27674076/1630171). With your example it would be okay to simply remove the newlines. A safer option would be to replace them with semicolons.

```
script = fetch.read().replace('\n', ';')
```

> 2. What is the correct way to invoke PowerShell from within Python so that it would run the script stored in `$script`?

Your command must be passed as an array. Also you cannot run a sequence of PowerShell statements via the `-File` parameter. Use `-Command` instead:

```
rc = subprocess.call(['powershell.exe', '-ExecutionPolicy', 'Bypass', '-Command', script])
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is happening because you are opening up PowerShell and it is automatically formatting it a specific way.

You could possibly do a for loop that goes through the command output and print without a /n.