# Fetching and evaluating a Python code from an HTTP response in Python 3.X

Tags: python, python-3.x, eval

I'm writing a Python script that gets an HTTP request as its input (namely, a url and some GET parameters). The response to the HTTP request is a piece of Python code representing a big Python dictionary. My script should evaluate the retrieved code and process the evaluated dictionary.

Had I been using Python 2.X, I would have done the follwoing:

```
import urllib
d = eval(urllib.request.urlopen(input_url).read())
process(d)
```

The problem is that I'm using Python 3.4, and the `read` method returns a `bytes` and not a `string` as in Python 2.X, so I can't use the `eval` function on it.

How do I evaluate the retrieved dictionary on Python 3.X?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert bytes to a Python string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-python-string)

Comment: `eval` can be dangerous. You might prefer [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) instead.

Comment: Does `json` format work in your case? If not; why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @rawing said in the comments, you'll need to decode the `bytes` into a string. You'll also probably want to use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) over `eval`, as the latter executes arbitrary code, and is unsafe.

Here's an example where I've uploaded a `dict` of literals as a [Github gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/eldridgejm/76c78b7d11a66162687b/raw/60a76770970715f859d1e3d33c8e2afcac296a31/gistfile1.txt):

```
import urllib.request
import ast

url = ("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/eldridgejm/76c78b7d11a66162687b/" +
      "raw/60a76770970715f859d1e3d33c8e2afcac296a31/gistfile1.txt")

r = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
d = ast.literal_eval(r.decode())

print(d)
```

Running the above prints:

```
{'bar': 42, 'baz': 'apple', 'foo': 41}
```

Comment: Don't use `ast.literal_eval()` for json text. You could [get the character encoding from http headers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14592762/4279). Or if the input is Python code then you could use `tokenizer.detect_encoding` module that recognize encoding declaration in Python source code. [Full example](https://gist.github.com/zed/dbdccd6d996b974e20cd)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Interesting, thanks. This answer assumes that the text is a `dict` of python literals. The only difference I am aware of in the case of literals is that `{"foo": (1,2,3)}` is not valid json. Do you know of others?

Comment: Python literals and json text are different formats. You shouldn't pass Python dict as a literal if json is enough.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Oh, I totally agree. The OP says that what he has is Python, and not json. Maybe his data *is* valid json, in which case he could use the json parser, but if he were to ask "What can I represent in Python, but not in json?", tuples are the only thing that I know (if we're restricted to literals).

Answer (score 1):

Using jme's example and if it is valid json which I think it may well be you can just use requests and use `.json`:

```
import requests

r  = requests.get("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/eldridgejm/76c78b7d11a66162687b/raw/60a76770970715f859d1e3d33c8e2afcac296a31/gistfile1.txt")
print(r.json())
{u'baz': u'apple', u'foo': 41, u'bar': 42}
```