# Unable to print the contents in the File using "urllib2"

Tags: python

I'm trying to  print the lines present in the  url file however,I'm getting an error that says:

```
    with html as ins:
    AttributeError: __exit__
```

Below posted is my code

```
  import urllib2

  response = urllib2.urlopen('------------------')

  html = response.read()
  counter = 0;
  with html as ins:
  array = []
  for line in ins:
     counter = counter+1
     print "cluster number is:", counter  
     print line
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: Yep..! i fixed the indentation but the problem is persisting

Comment: These two lines have wrong indentation still: `with html as ins:  array = []`. Please double check. Maybe this is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write the bytes from the url as is (no decoding/encoding):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import urllib2
import shutil
import sys
from contextlib import closing

with closing(urllib2.urlopen(url)) as response:
    shutil.copyfileobj(response, sys.stdout)
```

It expects that the character encoding used by `response` is the same character encoding your terminal uses otherwise you'll see mojibake. See [A good way to get the charset/encoding of an HTTP response in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14592762/4279).

---

Your code in the question contains multiple errors e.g.:

- wrong indentation
- it tries to use a `str` object as a context manager that leads to `AttributeError` (`__exit__` method is not defined) because `str` object does not implement [the context manager protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers)
- `for line in ins` is misleading: iterating over a string yields characters, not lines.

Comment: @Sebastian I'm looking for extracting the values and copying them in an array and print them line by line

Comment: @user3787061: Split your problem into a sequence of smaller tasks that could be understood easily e.g., 1. what do you want to print line-by-line? (is it the content of the url? what is it? is it a byte stream with a json text or with an html document or with a xml document?) 2. What does it mean *"extracting the values"* -- provide an example input as a string and the corresponding output array. Update your question. Do not put additional info in the comments.