# urllib2 reads web page with wrong unicode

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding, urllib2

I am trying to download a webpage using urlib2 in python.

```
response = urlopen(url, timeout=10)
html = response.read()

html[170:198]
print html[170:198]
```

But the 'á' character present in it is encoded as '\u0e41', which is no[Thai Character Sara Ae](http://www.marathon-studios.com/unicode/U0E41/Thai_Character_Sara_Ae), so far as I understand.

```
Cadeia Acion\u0e41ria da Empresa 
Cadeia Acionแria da Empresa
```

The output of the print command should be:

```
Cadeia Acionária da Empresa
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: related: [A good way to get the charset/encoding of an HTTP response in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14592762/4279)

Answer (score 0):

I found out what I was doing wrong. The webpage encoding was ISO-8859-1 and I wasn't decoding it at download time. Just adding the correct encoding after downloading it made everything work fine.

```
response = urlopen(url, timeout=10)
html = response.read()
html = unicode(html, 'ISO-8859-1')

html[170:198]
print html[170:198]
```

Now the string printed is:

```
Cadeia Acion\xe1ria da Empresa
Cadeia Acionária da Empresa
```

With the correct encoding.