# How Get Russian text from my page and put in HTML element using python

Tags: python, unicode

I get my text:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen("http://mypage/mytext.php")
page_source = response.read()
page_source
"({code:'\xd0\x9f\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82 \xd0\x92\xd1\x81\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbc!'});"
```

Then my must use:

```
driver.find_element_by_name("mytext").send_keys(page_source)
```

How convert page_source to russian characters ?

Comment: It already is russian, you are seeing the repr output when printed is `({code:'Привет Всем!'});
`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: it is a bytestring that should be decoded into Unicode text (utf-8 encoding is used in this case) otherwise the code may produce mojibake if some other part of the environment assumes a different encoding.

Answer (score 0):

`response.read()` returns bytes. To convert them to text, you need to know the corresponding character encoding:

```
text = response.read().decode(response.headers.getparam('charset'))
```

[A good way to get the charset/encoding of an HTTP response in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14592762/4279)

`.send_keys()` either accept Unicode text as is or you should pass bytes using character encoding its expects -- it may be different from the encoding used for the response:

```
...send_keys(text) # pass Unicode as is
...send_keys(text.encode(some_encoding)) # or pass bytes
```