# Utf-8 on windows python

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, utf-8

I have html file to read parse etc, it's encode on unicode (I saw it with the notepad) but when I tried

```
infile = open("path", "r") 
infile.read()
```

it fails and I had the famous error :

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position xx: character maps to undefined

So for test I tried to copy paste the contain of the file in a new one and save it in utf-8 and then tried to open it with codecs like this :

```
inFile = codecs.open("path", "r", encoding="utf-8")
outputStream = inFile.read()
```

But I get this error message :

> UnicodeEncodeError : 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\ufeff' in position 0: charcater maps to undefined

I really don't understand because I was created this file in utf8.

Comment: That's a [unicode BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Representations_of_byte_order_marks_by_encoding) it seems to be utf-16, can your try passing `encoding='utf-16'`

Comment: @EdChum I tried and the response is :
> UnicodeError: UTF-16 stream does not start with BOM

Comment: Can you post the raw input data just the first few lines or a link to the file, thanks. Another option is to skip the first couple of characters but really it should be able to open this without issue

Comment: It's an htm file from outlook which start like this : 
"<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"
xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">"

Comment: Are you sure you're getting that error during `.read()`!? The error during read would be "can't **decode**". It sounds like you're getting an error when writing to a file or printing to the terminal

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack Yes you're right, I get the error during the print to the terminal ! So all works but the terminal can't print some signs ?

Comment: Correct. Can you update your question so that it reflects the problem? The UnicodeEncodeErrors should contain the line number where the fault is so that you can identify the failing statement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`UnicodeEncodeError` suggests that the code fails while *encoding* Unicode text to bytes i.e., your actual code tries to print to Windows console. See [Python, Unicode, and the Windows console](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32176732/4279).

---

The link above fixes `UnicodeEncodeError`. The next issue is to find out what character encoding is used by the text in your `"path"` file. If `notepad.exe` shows the text correctly then it means that it is either encoded using `locale.getprefferedencoding(False)` (something like `cp1252` on Windows) or the file has [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

If you are sure that the encoding is utf-8 then pass it to `open()` directly. Don't use `codecs.open()`:

```
with open('path', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    html = file.read()
```

Sometimes, the input may contain text encoded using multiple (inconsistent) encodings e.g., smart quotes may be encoded using `cp1252` while the rest of html is utf-8 -- you could fix it using [`bs4.UnicodeDammit`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#inconsistent-encodings). See also [A good way to get the charset/encoding of an HTTP response in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14592762/4279)

Comment: If Notepad says “Unicode” (as the OP said) it means UTF-16. The other encodings are usually called “ANSI” (cp1252 and friends) and “UTF-8” (which is UTF-8 with BOM).

Comment: @roeland: yes. *"it's encode on unicode (I saw it with the notepad)"* from the question can be interpreted that way. The issue with that theory is that `codecs.open("path", encoding='utf-8').read()` returns `u'\ufeff'` i.e., `utf-8-sig` is more likely. `'utf-8'` encoding fails for both `BOM_UTF16_BE` and `BOM_UTF16_LE`.

Comment: Yeah, the question is a bit confusing as it involves two files, the original file in “Unicode”, and the file he re-saved as “UTF-8”.

Comment: @roeland: anyway the issue is `UnicodeEncodeError` i.e., when OP tries to print Unicode text to Windows console.

Comment: Aha, I see. That was subtle

Answer (score 1):

The original file probably uses `utf-16` (Windows uses the term *UNICODE* for that encoding).

UTF-8 encoded files on Windows normally starts with a magic number `b"\xef\xbb\xbf"` (the UTF-8 encoding of U+FEFF) so applications reading that file know it was saved as UTF-8 and not some ANSI code page. `utf8-sig` which will automatically discard that character.

Comment: As a side-note: Don't use `codecs.open`. On Py3, you can pass an `encoding` argument to regular `open`, and on Py2.7, you can import `io.open` (which is the same as Py3's built-in `open`) and do the same. `codecs.open` has some dumb quirks (e.g. doesn't do universal new line handling).

Answer (score 1):

In anticipation of the OP to update question to reflect the actual problem, the issue is caused by the encoding of the terminal not being defined.

The Windows console is notoriously poor when it comes to Unicode support. For ultimate support, see https://pypi.python.org/pypi/win_unicode_console. Essentially, install "win_unicode_console" (`pip install win_unicode_console`). Then at the top of your code:

```
import win_unicode_console
win_unicode_console.enable()
```

You may also need to use a suitable font - See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5750227/1554386

As you're using an input with a UTF-8 BOM, you should use the `utf_8_sig` codec so that the BOM is stripped before working with the contents.

As this is Python 3, you don't need to use the `codecs` module to set encoding when using `open()`.

Putting it together it would look like:

```
import win_unicode_console
win_unicode_console.enable()

infile = open("path", "r", encoding="utf_8_sig")
```

Comment: it is best to avoid modifying the script. You could run it using `run` module instead (a part of `win-unicode-console`): `py -m run your-unicode-printing-script.py` or if it is appropriate in your case then put `win_unicode_console.enable()` call into `sitecustomize` or `usercustomize` modules.

Comment: Is this package still maintained? What does it do specifically?