# Python, UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

I want to write the HTML of a website to the file I created, tough I decode to utf-8 but still it puts up a error like this, I use `print(data1)` and the html is printed properlyand I am using *python 3.5.0*

```
import re
import urllib.request

city = input("city name")   
url = "http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/"+city+"/forecasts/latest"
data  = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
data1 = data.decode("utf-8")
f = open("C:\\Users\\Gopal\\Desktop\\test\\scrape.txt","w")
f.write(data1)
```

Comment: unrelated: (1) use `urllib.parse.quote(city, safe='')` (2) in general, the server may use a different character encoding, see [A good way to get the charset/encoding of an HTTP response in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14592762/4279) (3) use `with`-statement to close the file, otherwise nothing might be written to disk due to buffering.

Answer (score 3):

You've opened a file with the *default system encoding*:

```
f = open("C:\\Users\\Gopal\\Desktop\\test\\scrape.txt", "w")
```

You need to specify your encoding explicitly:

```
f = open("C:\\Users\\Gopal\\Desktop\\test\\scrape.txt", "w", encoding='utf8')
```

See the [`open()` function documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

> In text mode, if encoding is not specified the encoding used is platform dependent: `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` is called to get the current locale encoding.

On your system, the default is a codec that cannot handle your data.

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open("C:\\Users\\Gopal\\Desktop\\test\\scrape.txt","w",encoding='utf8')


f.write(data1)
```

This should work, it did for me

Comment: This does not seem to add anything to a previously posted answer.