# Python: parsing UNICODE characters using bs4

Tags: python, unicode, beautifulsoup

I am building a python3 web crawler/scraper using bs4. The program crashes whenever it meets a UNICODE code character like a Chinese symbol. How do I modify my scraper so that it supports UNICODE?

Here's the code:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def crawlForData(url):
        r = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.read(),'html.parser')
        result = [i.text.replace('\n', ' ').strip() for i in soup.find_all('p')]
        for p in result:
                print(p)

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adivasi'
crawlForData(url)
```

Comment: Your example seems to work for me fine. Are you sure this isn't a problem with the IDE you're running it on ? maybe your shell doesn't support unicode ?

Comment: Do you use Python 3.x? The usage of the `print` function seems to indicate this, but I'd like to be sure.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Python 3

Comment: the posted example works for me too! may be add an arbitrary print before printing ```p``` that way you know if it is a problem with the shell or IDE and not with parsing. It works in OSX Terminal and PyCharm

Comment: In fact I have got a weird issue now. The code doesn't even run if I try it from command line. Works in PyCharm IDE unless there are unicode characters.

Comment: "The program crashes".  Show the full error traceback.  My guess is it is a `UnicodeEncodeError` on `print(p)` and you are running on Windows and the terminal encoding is not UTF-8.  The people using Linux are using UTF-8 and it works.  Try `print(repr(p))` or use an IDE that supports UTF-8.

Comment: related: [A good way to get the charset/encoding of an HTTP response in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14592762/4279)

Comment: @MarkTolonen Yes, I am running on Windows and it is a `UnicodeEncodeError`.

Comment: Which line has the crash? Edit your question and show the full traceback of the error message.  You are using Unicode strings by default in Python 3, so it is probably the console or IDE you are using on Windows that isn't supporting the characters you are trying to print.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `unicode()` method. It decodes unicode strings.

or a way to go is

```
content.decode('utf-8','ignore')
```

where `content` is your string

The complete solution may be:

```
html = urllib2.urlopen("your url")
content = html.read().decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
```

Comment: @MagicMysteryBro please accept this question if you find it helpful