# urlopen choking me with newlines

Tags: python, postgresql, unicode, urlopen

I'm scraping simple textfiles from a url.

```
def scrape_contents_ex(url):
    data = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    return data.read()
```

The problem is that the string it yields is choked with newline and tab characters "\t", "\r" etc.

Example:

Here is the webpage
[image]

When I print string output in python, it renders with various \characters:

[image]

I don't know how to properly handle the output I read from urlopen.  I want to store these contents in postgresql.  Moreover, I have another complication where the content very likely yield unicode results (chinese characters, cyrillic, etc).

What is the proper and robust way to read and store this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the str.split() method, though there are a lot of options to solve this particular problem.

From the python 3.5.1 docs:

```
>>> '1,2,3'.split(',')
['1', '2', '3']
>>> '1,2,3'.split(',', maxsplit=1)
['1', '2,3']
>>> '1,2,,3,'.split(',')
['1', '2', '', '3', '']
```

You would want something like

```
return data.read().split('\n\t')
```

The result is a list of strings occurring between any instances of '\n\t' in your original string.

Comment: Totally unrelated to what you asked, but I found the requests library to be much better than urllib2.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use libraries 'urllib', 'urllib2' to avoid ecoding.

you can check following link
https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html

Answer (score 0):

`foo` is a bytestring in your case. If it represents text; you should decode it into Unicode before storing it in PostgreSQL: `text = foo.decode(character_encoding)` The charset may depend on the Content-Type. See [A good way to get the charset/encoding of an HTTP response in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14592762/4279).

Then you type `foo` on the prompt, `ipython` tries to display the `foo` object and it may call `repr(foo)`.

What you see: `"a\nb"` (the result of the `repr()` call) is a printable representation of the Python object with the type `str` (`type(foo) == str`). Python string literals use the same syntax. The backslash is special inside string *literals* e.g., `"\n"` is a *single* character (a newline—`ord("\n") == 10`). If you want to create a string that contains two character: `backslash + n` then you have to escape the backslash or use raw string literals:

```
>>> "\\n" == r"\n" != "\n"
True
```