# I am not getting data in proper language of html by request package

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.8

I am trying to scrape a Japanese website (a trimmed down sample below):

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="euc-jp">
</head>
<body>
<h3>不審者の出没</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to get data of this html by request package using:

```
response = requests.get(url)
```

I am getting data from h3 field in as: 
'¡ÊÂçÊ¬' and unicode value of it is like this:

```
'\xa4\xaa\xa4\xaa\xa4\xa4\xa4\xbf\'
```

but when I load this html from a file or from a local wsgi server (tried with Django to serve a static html page) then I get:

```
不審者の出没. It's actual data.
```

Now I am not understanding how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python requests.get() returns improperly decoded text instead of UTF-8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44203397/python-requests-get-returns-improperly-decoded-text-instead-of-utf-8)

Comment: Can you show us the code? How are you accessing the text of the response? How are you parsing it to find the h3 field?

Comment: Also, is that really the same data? Because those bytes are definitely not euc-jp for 不審者の出没. For one thing, the trailing backlash is illegal, but even without that, those bytes decode as おおいた.

Comment: @abarnert It's not same data. I have written only a sample data.

Comment: @AmiHollander After getting response, encoding of response is 'ISO-8859-1'. Due to this, I am not geting actual data

Comment: @abarnert If I print the response then I am not getting actual html.