# python lxml can't parse japanese in some case

Tags: python, python-requests, lxml

I am using lxml 4.5.0 to scraping data from website.

it works well in the following example

```
chrome_ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 " \
            "(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3864.0 Safari/537.36"

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update({'User-Agent': chrome_ua})
    resp = s.get('https://www.yahoo.co.jp')
    parser = etree.HTMLParser()
    tree = etree.parse(StringIO(resp.text), parser)
    result = tree.xpath('//*[@id="tabTopics1"]/a')[0]

result.text
```

as the `result.text` give me the right text `'ニュース'`

but when I try another side, it failed to prase the japanese properly.

```
chrome_ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 " \
            "(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3864.0 Safari/537.36"

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update({'User-Agent': chrome_ua})
    resp = s.get('https://travel.rakuten.co.jp/')
    parser = etree.HTMLParser()
    tree = etree.parse(StringIO(resp.text), parser)
    result = tree.xpath('//*[@id="rt-nav-box"]/li[1]/a')[0]

result.text
```

the `result.text` give me `'å\x9b½å\x86\x85æ\x97\x85è¡\x8c'` , it should be `'国内旅行'`

I tried to use `parser = etree.HTMLParser(encoding='utf-8')`, but it still not work.

How can I make lxml parse japanese properly in this case?

Comment: You may want to use BeautifulSoup instead - it's geared for messy HTML and messy Unicode.

Comment: @AKX yeah, I tried BeautifulSoup at frist. but I found it does not supports XPATH, so I turn into lxml

Comment: I also tried selenium, it works well. but I don't want to use selenium since it need a browser working background and cause much overhead. I do not need to run javascript or something else but just parse the html.

Comment: Somewhere the `utf-8` in the `meta` in the  second web site header gets lost; the other web site has the same but there it works. Forcing recoding works: `print (bytes(result.text, encoding='latin-1').decode('utf8'))`, but you cannot know in advance when that is necessary so no proper "solution".

Comment: `StringIO(resp.content.decode('utf-8'))`

Comment: You can try this. You don't have to worry about the encoding.
from simplified_scrapy import req
html = req.get('https://travel.rakuten.co.jp/')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using

```
print(resp.encoding)
```

you can see it used `ISO-8859-1` to convert `resp.content` to `resp.text`

but you can get directly `resp.content` and decode it with different encoding

```
StringIO( resp.content.decode('utf-8') )
```

---

Using module [chardet](https://chardet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) you can try to detect what encoding you should use

```
print( chardet.detect(resp.content) )
```

Result

```
{'encoding': 'utf-8', 'confidence': 0.99, 'language': ''}
```

---

```
import requests
from lxml import etree
from io import StringIO
import chardet

chrome_ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 " \
            "(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3864.0 Safari/537.36"

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update({'User-Agent': chrome_ua})
    resp = s.get('https://travel.rakuten.co.jp/')

    print(resp.encoding)
    print( chardet.detect(resp.content) )
    detected_encoding = chardet.detect(resp.content)['encoding']

    parser = etree.HTMLParser()
    #tree = etree.parse(StringIO(resp.content.decode('utf-8')), parser)
    tree = etree.parse(StringIO(resp.content.decode(detected_encoding)), parser)
    result = tree.xpath('//*[@id="rt-nav-box"]/li[1]/a')[0]

result.text
```

---

**EDIT:** as @usr2564301 found in answer

[python requests.get() returns improperly decoded text instead of UTF-8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44203397/python-requests-get-returns-improperly-decoded-text-instead-of-utf-8)

it can be resolved with

```
 resp.encoding = resp.apparent_encoding
```

which uses `chardet` to recognize encoding.

Comment: Is it unrelated to the fact that `meta charSet="utf-8"'` in the first seems parsed but is skipped as `meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"` in the second test site? Is that something requests should have seen?

Comment: I don't know how `requests` check encoding but before HTML and `<meta>` it gets headers and it may use header `'content-type'` to recognize encoding. If you check `resp.headers['content-type']` then you see that first page sends `text/html; charset=UTF-8` but second sends only `text/html` without encoding.

Comment: see [python requests.get() returns improperly decoded text instead of UTF-8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44203397/python-requests-get-returns-improperly-decoded-text-instead-of-utf-8) - it seems it uses only header `'content-type'` to recognize encoding and for `text/html` it uses `ISO-8859-1` as default value.

Comment: A-ha! Excellent find -- want to close this question as a duplicate? This one merely says "in some case", the dup correctly names the underlying issue.

Comment: -- note in case, all OP's code needs is this additional line: `resp.encoding = resp.apparent_encoding`. As explained in the duplicate, requests already does a `chardet` in the background.

Comment: @usr2564301 good point - I missed `apparent_encoding` in that answer.

Comment: @furas oh, I did not notice that the problem was caused by requests. thanks for pointing out the real problem is. Thanks a lot!

Comment: maybe we can advise requests developer to update their default value to 'UTF-8' if the website don't specify it in header since now is the decade for HTML5. I think that will fit the real case better and make less people confused by it.

Comment: but what if page has only `text/html` and it uses `ISO-8859-1` in HTML ? I think this problem is so rare and there is no need to change it.

Comment: I think it may have a higher possibility for the page is using `UTF-8` in that case. since HTML5 have a higher market share now and the default for HTML5 is `UTF-8`. I don't know, I am not professional in HTML standard. whatever, thank you!