# Python Variable Encoding

Tags: python, json

I have written a program that reads csv files written in various languages (i.e. German) and uploads them to a MySQL database for searching.

A cell containing "Kreuter Bůch. Strasbourg: W. Rihel (Strasbourg)" gets uploaded properly to the database.

```
mysql> select * from metadata where id = 484203\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
        id: 484203
element_id: 98049
  field_id: 1005
     value: Kreuter Bůch. Strasbourg: W. Rihel (Strasbourg)
1 row in set (0.16 sec)
```

The API returns the correct value:

```
curl http://server/metadata/api/484203
{
  "id" : 484203,
  "elementId" : 98049,
  "fieldId" : 1005,
  "name" : "publisher",
  "value" : "Kreuter Bůch. Strasbourg: W. Rihel (Strasbourg)"
}
```

The assigned value in python is incorrect.

```
{'id': 484203, 'elementId': 98049, 'fieldId': 1005, 'name': 'publisher', 'value': 'Kreuter BÅ¯ch. Strasbourg: W. Rihel (Strasbourg)'}
```

Sample Code

```
    url = f"http://server/metadata/api/"
    payload = json.dumps({
        "elementId": elementId,
        "fieldId": fieldId,
        "value": value
    })
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    data = json.loads(response.text)
    print(data)
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: probably check https://stackoverflow.com/q/44203397/4046632

Comment: Also better `data = response.json()`

Comment: Why is data = response.json() better than json.loads(response.text)?

Comment: more readable, no need to `import json`. It's a convenience method of `Response` object

Comment: The same way, instead of using `json.dumps` and then `data=` you can use `json=` and pass the dict direectly

Answer (score 1):

```
    response = requests.request("Get", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    response.encoding = "utf8"
    data = response.json()
```

Python assumed that the returned response was encoded in "ascii".