# python requests.text stuck on large content

Tags: python, python-requests

I use the `requests` library to fetch logs and look up certain strings for other purposes. These logs are quite large. I can print the content/text and length of most logs (output 1). However, there is one log that I can't seem to access using `response.text`. When I set a breakpoint in my editor, it gets stuck at `return response.text` every time (output 2). I don't know if this is caused by the size of the log because other larger logs have passed this point. I am not an advanced user of either Python or the `requests` library. I hope someone with more experience can share some insights on this. Thanks in advance.

```
def fetch_webpage_content(url):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, headers = my_headers)
        print("got it")
        print(len(response.content))
        #print(response.text)
        #print(response.content)
        response.raise_for_status()
        return response.text
    except requests.RequestException as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while fetching web page content: {e}")
        return None

def process_webpage(url, pattern):
    text = fetch_webpage_content(url)
    print("in process_webpage")
    if text is not None:
        match = search_pattern(pattern, text)
        if match:
            return match.group()
        return ''
    else:
        return ''
```

output 1

```
got it
33131960
in process_webpage
got it
9383326
in process_webpage

got it
33131960
in process_webpage
got it
13795885
in process_webpage
```

output 2

```
got it
33131960
in process_webpage
got it
25565370
```

Comment: My problem appears to be solved by adding `response.encoding = "utf-8"` before  `return response.text`. Pasting the remark from Bubak here: `You should also be aware that you should not access r.text before setting the r.encoding to desired value (using r.apparent_encoding or any method desirable). `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44203397/python-requests-get-returns-improperly-decoded-text-instead-of-utf-8

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying that this line:

```
return response.text
```

is the last line to run, then that is likely because you are only calling that function. You have broken your code up into two functions, and if the "try" block for this function runs, then `return response.text` is the final line to run in that function. You would need to then separately call the other function for it to run.

Instead of it not printing the whole log due to size, as you suggest, I would assume it is instead not scraping all of the data that you think it is.

Comment: Thanks, @samsupertaco, for sharing your thoughts. I am not sure if I am following you here. "You would need to then separately call the other function for it to run." Can you be a little more specific about this? I did call `fetch_webpage_content()` in `process_webpage()`. Are you suggesting I assign the result to a variable and then return that variable? I have tried that. The script will hang on the line of the assignment. "It is instead not scraping all of the data that you think it is." If not use `requests.text`, what else could I use to get the content of a page as a string?