# Getting Unicode Error when i get api and print it

Tags: python, json, flask

**Explanation** :
When I print new_movie_data it gives Unicode Error:

> Error : UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 4167-4177: character maps to <undefined>

My CODE :

```
@app.route("/add", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def add():
    add_form = FindMovieForm()
    if add_form.validate_on_submit():
        movie_title = add_form.add_movie.data
        response = requests.get(f"{MOVIE_DB_SEARCH}{api_key}&query={movie_title}")
        new_movie_data = response.json()["results"]
        redirect(url_for("home"))
    return render_template("add.html", form=add_form)
```

I want to print `new_movie_data` in JSON so I can parse this data into another template which shows on     a different page. I tried different methods of applying UTF-8 into `new-movie-data` but none of them work.

Comment: Please include the full error dump so we can see where it failed.

Comment: I don't understand why you're using `print()` at all.  There is no call to `print()` in this code, so this cannot be the real code with the error...

Comment: Sorry i didnt put print(new_movie_data) in code .... 
Full error : return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 4167-4177: character maps to <undefined>
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jan/2024 13:52:00] "POST /add HTTP/1.1" 500 -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request and response seems to be the issue (not Flask).

Since you mentioned "MOVIE_DB_SEARCH" I took this URL and API for my minimal reproducible example:

```
import requests

# Given those definitions
movie_title = 'Ghost Busters'

MOVIE_DB_SEARCH = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie' 

api_key = ''  # enter your API key here
bearer_token = ''  # enter your Bearer token here

url = f"{MOVIE_DB_SEARCH}?query={movie_title}&api_key={api_key}"
headers_with_bearer = {"accept": "application/json", "Authorization": f"Bearer {bearer_token}"}

# This would be the way to handle request and response
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers_with_bearer)

# Print some debug information (HTTP status, encoding, MIME-type, content)
print(response.status_code)  # should be 200
print(response.encoding)  # should be utf-8
print(response.headers['Content-Type'])  # should be application/json
print(response.content)

new_movie_data = response.json()["results"]
```

Probably you have more chance when taking the binary-stream from `response.content`.
See: [python requests.get() returns improperly decoded text instead of UTF-8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44203397/python-requests-get-returns-improperly-decoded-text-instead-of-utf-8)

#### See also

The Movie Database API docs and reference:

- [Authenticate using the query-parameter API key](https://developer.themoviedb.org/docs/authentication-application#api-key)
- [Authorize using the Bearer Token](https://developer.themoviedb.org/docs/authentication-application#bearer-token)
- [Search Movie](https://developer.themoviedb.org/reference/search-movie)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @hc_dev it's working. The problem is in my `MOVIE_DB_SEARCH` URL and in the request: I put `api_key` first and then the query, but in your code the query is first and `api_key` second.

Here is my Movie-DB-search URL and response:

```
MOVIE_DB_SEARCH = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key="
response = requests.get(f"{MOVIE_DB_SEARCH}{api_key}&query={movie_title}")
```

I also didn't put any headers in the request but it also works without them.